# What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

What is the difference between `null` and `undefined` in JavaScript?

Comment: I always thought: `null` is you set it to empty, `undefined` it's empty because it has not been set. Or `null` is empty on purpose, while `undefined` is still empty. Basically it shows intent.

Comment: See also [Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/801032/1048572)

Comment: NaN. See for yourself. console.log(null-undefined). The difference between null and undefined is NaN. (Note that this is an attempt at humour, before you flame me for misunderstanding the question.)

Comment: With `null` you use it generally to erase the contents of a variable, with `undefined` it generally comes with input when there hasn't been set a value yet.

Comment: See also   [is-it-better-to-return undefined or null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980559/is-it-better-to-return-undefined-or-null-from-a-javascript-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `null` means the variable was declared, but have a null value. A null is a special value like any other possible value. `undefined` means that the variable you're trying to read/reference did not was not assigned with any value.

Comment: As a side note, it's worth noting that while the originator of `null` called it his "billion-dollar mistake" ([Tony Hoare](https://qconlondon.com/london-2009/qconlondon.com/london-2009/speaker/Tony+Hoare.html)), JavaScript happily decided to multiply that mistake by 2. Happy debugging!

Comment: There is a lint rule  explaining that undefined is preferred. See palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-null-keyword

Comment: The TypeScript Coding guidelines recommend using only undefined and discouraging the use of null values (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines#null-and-undefined)

Answer (score 1580, accepted):

`undefined` means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned a value :

```js
var testVar;
console.log(testVar); //shows undefined
console.log(typeof testVar); //shows undefined
```

`null` is an assignment value. It can be assigned to a variable as a representation of no value :

```js
var testVar = null;
console.log(testVar); //shows null
console.log(typeof testVar); //shows object
```

From the preceding examples, it is clear that `undefined` and `null` are two distinct types: `undefined` is a type itself (undefined) while `null` is an object.

Proof :

```js
console.log(null === undefined) // false (not the same type)
console.log(null == undefined) // true (but the "same value")
console.log(null === null) // true (both type and value are the same)
```

and

```
null = 'value' // Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand side
undefined = 'value' // 'value'
```

Comment: Quote from the book Professional JS For Web Developers (Wrox): "You may wonder why the typeof operator returns 'object' for a value that is null. This was actually an error in the original JavaScript implementation that was then copied in ECMAScript. Today, it is rationalized that null is considered a placeholder for an object, even though, technically, it is a primitive value."

Comment: the variable might as well not be defined at all. for example:
    console.log(typeof(abc));
    undefined

Comment: The comment from Nir O. is very important. If I want to have a variable that has no value in the beginning, I write "... = null", eg "myvar = null". This way - when I mistype "if (myxar == null) {...}" - the if block is not executed. I don't have this advantage with undefined: myvar = undefined; myvar = 4; if (typeof myxar == "undefined") { ...}

Comment: @Wolfgang Adamec, error-free programming is not about mistypes.

Comment: so basically null value means a variable has been explicitly set as (no value = null) or has been initialized and defined to be nothing. While undefined means. it was probably never initialized or if it was it was never defined.

Comment: Why does null==undefined return true?

Comment: @khunshan pretty bizaare that one but if you use === (the proper equality operator) then they are not.  This is because the types are different null is an object & undefined is undefined.  See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for more info

Comment: **undefined means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned** not really..  `var a = {};` then `a.abc === undefined is true`..but if you do `a.n=undefined;`  now a is {a:undefined}... so regardless if var was declared or not it was undefined !!!!

Comment: From the preceding examples, it is clear that there is no point of having undefined and null as separate concepts.

Comment: @merrr: There are cases when it makes perfect sense to test for undefined instead of null, for example: If you make use of associative arrays which serve as dynamic containers for some type of data...you may not know which index exists, so you have to find out first:  if (typeof niceArray['index1']['option_xy'] !== 'undefined') { ... } typeof will return 'undefined' even if the identifier has never been declared...pretty cool...and you cannot test for null instead, because Javascript will throw a reference error.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I agree. Don't program according to how often you hit the wrong key on the keyboard. Well said.

Comment: @all, I think a real life example is better, i have declared a variable node with var node. If this variable has no value node == null and node == undefined both are true. If i want to know if this variable is declared i use node === undefined and that result is false. These are the most common practices for conditions. Some will use node == undefined also for variables that need to be declared and i think thats bad practice. The null gives information about the variable and says i need to be declared. Thats usefull information for the developer.

Comment: @HermanVanDerBlom That's incorrect though. checking for `node === undefined` while `node` hasn't been declared will throw a `ReferenceError` because `node` is indeed (pun intended) undefined. You probably mean to check whether `typeof node === "undefined"`

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that since this answer was written, ES6 has introduced default function parameters, which work differently for `null` and `undefined`. Wtih `function foo(bar = 'default') { return bar; }`, then `foo(null) === null` but `foo() === foo(undefined) === 'default'`. React props also work similarly, so there are more reasons now than before to intentionally pass `undefined` rather than `null`.

Comment: FWIW, @user3597009 - `null` is a *value*, not a *type*. IMHO, its arbitrary what *type* JS says `null` is; its not particularly meaningful to talk about the "type of null" - in any language. As you know, its a pre-defined value that you assign to a variable so that later you can ask "does this variable have value null?"  E.g. `x = null;` ... `if (x === null) ...`. It would not be meaningful to ask "does this variable have *type* null?"

Comment: `x = {}` and then `x["hede"] === undefined` is `true` so "undefined means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned a value" <- this is just confusing and probably wrong.

Comment: If something is undefined, it means it has been unassigned. 
If something is null, it means it has been assigned a null value.

Comment: @nurettin In that example, basically every imaginable object property is "implicitly declared". This is consistent with other instances of handling "undeclared" properties, so from that perspective the statement remains correct.

Comment: @user777 The way I read this, the problem is more saying "declared" where the intention appears to be "initialized".

Comment: Why is this answer marked as correct? You can assign undefined to a variable “let foo = undefined;”

Comment: I vote for the elimination or either one. In both case there is no value and it just gives headaches in test cases. There is data or there is not. Intent to leave a variable empty should not be at the cost of overall confusion and complexity among us developers. I cannot see a single case where null would be useful.

Comment: null was invented to say : this variable should have an object reference but currently has none. So we put null. (source: https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_1st_edition_june_1997.pdf) text exact: "Null is a primitive value that represents the null, empty, or nonexistent reference"

Answer (score 726):

The difference can be explained with toilet tissue holder:

- A non-zero value is like a holder with roll of toilet tissue and there's tissue still on the tube.
- A zero value is like a holder with an empty toilet tissue tube.
- A null value is like a holder that doesn't even have a tissue tube.
- An undefined value is similar to the holder itself being missing.

[image]

Comment: Could you include the attribution for the image source, please?

Comment: @Vega Unfortunately no, I don't remember where I got it from other than somewhere on imgur.com and that's probably from a repost, not the ORIGINAL source. Not even the embedded link here gives any clue of who posted this version, so I can't really search for it either.

Comment: @SebastianNorr "I don't remember where I got it from other than somewhere on imgur.com" ->  so is it `undefined` or `null` in that case?

Comment: `let toiletPaperIn2020 = undefined;`

Comment: @Erowlin It is closer to being `null` because I remember that the image comes from imgur, so it isn't totally unknown. The `undefined` would be more like "I have no idea where it came from".

Comment: @hakre is this what you mean? https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9M2J.png As I have already said before, I don't have the information anymore where it came from, not even editing the post shows it to me, other than that the image comes from imgur.com This link is what I get when I right click & choose "Copy link address", I still don't know who originally uploaded this image or the full url to it.

Comment: This is probably a problem with the Stackoverflow UI when uploading images and not having the user to certify whether a) it is the users original work that is contributed under license or b) to annotate the upload with the appropriate license information. Could be Meta material.

Comment: I disagree with the toilet picture, it actually gives a bad representation of the problem.

Comment: `undefined` cannot be an empty wall if the holder represents the variable.
In this representation, `undefined` is an empty holder while null is an empty holder with post-it note `empty`.  (so the unfortunate user knows it's useless to ask the cleaning lady for toilet paper).
That also show why many developers are confused : should I put an `empty` post-it note on an uninitialized variable or will everyone understand that `empty` means *empty* ?
e.g. is the lack op toilet paper intentional or not ?

Comment: And the RAM is the bathroom

Comment: @mercury - "And the RAM is the bathroom" - wouldn't that be the hard disk? RAM should be the cleaning lady's hands.

Answer (score 91):

I picked this from [here](http://www.gibdon.com/2006/05/javascript-difference-between-null-and.html)

> The undefined value is a primitive value used when a variable has not
>   been assigned a value.
>
> The null value is a primitive value that represents the null, empty,
>   or non-existent reference.

When you declare a variable through var and do not give it a value, it will have the value undefined. By itself, if you try to WScript.Echo() or alert() this value, you won't see anything. However, if you append a blank string to it then suddenly it'll appear:

```
var s;
WScript.Echo(s);
WScript.Echo("" + s);
```

You can declare a variable, set it to null, and the behavior is identical except that you'll see "null" printed out versus "undefined". This is a small difference indeed.

You can even compare a variable that is undefined to null or vice versa, and the condition will be true:

```
undefined == null
null == undefined
```

They are, however, considered to be two different types. While undefined is a type all to itself, null is considered to be a special object value. You can see this by using typeof() which returns a string representing the general type of a variable:

```
var a;
WScript.Echo(typeof(a));
var b = null;
WScript.Echo(typeof(b));
```

Running the above script will result in the following output:

```
undefined
object
```

Regardless of their being different types, they will still act the same if you try to access a member of either one, e.g. that is to say they will throw an exception. With WSH you will see the dreaded "'varname' is null or not an object" and that's if you're lucky (but that's a topic for another article).

You can explicitely set a variable to be undefined, but I highly advise against it. I recommend only setting variables to null and leave undefined the value for things you forgot to set. At the same time, I really encourage you to always set every variable. JavaScript has a scope chain different than that of C-style languages, easily confusing even veteran programmers, and setting variables to null is the best way to prevent bugs based on it.

Another instance where you will see undefined pop up is when using the delete operator. Those of us from a C-world might incorrectly interpret this as destroying an object, but it is not so. What this operation does is remove a subscript from an Array or a member from an Object. For Arrays it does not effect the length, but rather that subscript is now considered undefined.

```
var a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
delete a[1];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
WScript.Echo((i+".) "+a[i]);
```

The result of the above script is:

```
0.) a
1.) undefined
2.) c
```

You will also get undefined returned when reading a subscript or member that never existed.

The difference between null and undefined is: JavaScript will never set anything to null, that's usually what we do. While we can set variables to undefined, we prefer null because it's not something that is ever done for us. When you're debugging this means that anything set to null is of your own doing and not JavaScript. Beyond that, these two special values are nearly equivalent.

Comment: Really a good answer. But just to point out, when u checked "undefined == null" the type checking was not strict. Hence it returned "true". If you check "undefined === null", it would return false.

Comment: It's worth noting that while this comment was true in '11, with the advent of optional function params, emergence of type-checking systems like Flow, and pervasiveness of React (all of which treat undefined and null very differently), the old wisdom of generally using null rather than undefined no longer holds so strictly. undefined is actually preferable to null in many cases where you want to explicitly use the default value (e.g. for an optional param or optional React prop).

Comment: From https://blog.devgenius.io/typescript-when-to-use-null-undefined-or-empty-array-d45244ffc565  “in my point of view, better not to use null at all and prefer undefined.”

Answer (score 69):

Please read the following carefully. It should remove all your doubts regarding the difference between `null` and `undefined` in JavaScript. Also, you can use the utility function at the end of this answer to get more specific types of variables.

In JavaScript we can have the following types of variables:

1. Undeclared Variables
2. Declared but Unassigned Variables
3. Variables assigned with literal `undefined`
4. Variables assigned with literal `null`
5. Variables assigned with anything other than `undefined` or `null`

The following explains each of these cases one by one:

1. **Undeclared Variables**

   - Can only be checked with the `typeof` operator which returns string **'undefined'**
   - Cannot be checked with the loose equality operator ( `== undefined` ), let alone the strict equality operator ( `=== undefined` ),
     as well as **if-statements** and **ternary operators** ( `? :` ) — these throw Reference Errors
2. **Declared but Unassigned Variables**

   - `typeof` returns string **'undefined'**
   - `==` check with `null` returns `true`
   - `==` check with `undefined` returns `true`
   - `===` check with `null` returns `false`
   - `===` check with `undefined` returns `true`
   - Is **falsy** to **if-statements** and **ternary operators** ( `? :` )
3. **Variables assigned with literal `undefined`**
   These variables are treated exactly the same as **Declared But Unassigned Variables**.
4. **Variables assigned with literal `null`**

   - `typeof` returns string **'object'**
   - `==` check with `null` returns `true`
   - `==` check with `undefined` returns `true`
   - `===` check with `null` returns `true`
   - `===` check with `undefined` returns `false`
   - Is **falsy** to **if-statements** and **ternary operators** ( `? :` )
5. **Variables assigned with anything other than `undefined` or `null`**

   - typeof returns one of the following strings: **'bigint'**, **'boolean'**, **'function'**, **'number'**, **'object'**, **'string'**, **'symbol'**

Following provides the algorithm for correct type checking of a variable:

1. Get the `typeof` our variable and return it if it isn't **'object'**
2. Check for `null`, as `typeof null` returns **'object'** as well
3. Evaluate **Object.prototype.toString.call(o)** with a switch statement to return a more precise value. `Object`'s `toString` method returns strings that look like **'[object ConstructorName]'** for native/host objects. For all other objects (user-defined objects), it always returns **'[object Object]'**
4. If that last part is the case (the stringified version of the variable being **'[object Object]'**) and the parameter **returnConstructorBoolean** is `true`, it will try to get the name of the constructor by `toString`-ing it and extracting the name from there. If the constructor can't be reached, **'object'** is returned as usual. If the string doesn't contain its name, **'anonymous'** is returned

(supports all types up to ECMAScript 2020)

```
function TypeOf(o, returnConstructorBoolean) {
  const type = typeof o

  if (type !== 'object') return type
  if (o === null)        return 'null'

  const toString = Object.prototype.toString.call(o)

  switch (toString) {
    // Value types: 6
    case '[object BigInt]':            return 'bigint'
    case '[object Boolean]':           return 'boolean'
    case '[object Date]':              return 'date'
    case '[object Number]':            return 'number'
    case '[object String]':            return 'string'
    case '[object Symbol]':            return 'symbol'

    // Error types: 7
    case '[object Error]':             return 'error'
    case '[object EvalError]':         return 'evalerror'
    case '[object RangeError]':        return 'rangeerror'
    case '[object ReferenceError]':    return 'referenceerror'
    case '[object SyntaxError]':       return 'syntaxerror'
    case '[object TypeError]':         return 'typeerror'
    case '[object URIError]':          return 'urierror'

    // Indexed Collection and Helper types: 13
    case '[object Array]':             return 'array'
    case '[object Int8Array]':         return 'int8array'
    case '[object Uint8Array]':        return 'uint8array'
    case '[object Uint8ClampedArray]': return 'uint8clampedarray'
    case '[object Int16Array]':        return 'int16array'
    case '[object Uint16Array]':       return 'uint16array'
    case '[object Int32Array]':        return 'int32array'
    case '[object Uint32Array]':       return 'uint32array'
    case '[object Float32Array]':      return 'float32array'
    case '[object Float64Array]':      return 'float64array'
    case '[object ArrayBuffer]':       return 'arraybuffer'
    case '[object SharedArrayBuffer]': return 'sharedarraybuffer'
    case '[object DataView]':          return 'dataview'

    // Keyed Collection types: 2
    case '[object Map]':               return 'map'
    case '[object WeakMap]':           return 'weakmap'

    // Set types: 2
    case '[object Set]':               return 'set'
    case '[object WeakSet]':           return 'weakset'

    // Operation types: 3
    case '[object RegExp]':            return 'regexp'
    case '[object Proxy]':             return 'proxy'
    case '[object Promise]':           return 'promise'

    // Plain objects
    case '[object Object]':
      if (!returnConstructorBoolean)
        return type

      const _prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(o)
      if (!_prototype)              
        return type

      const _constructor = _prototype.constructor
      if (!_constructor)            
        return type

      const matches = Function.prototype.toString.call(_constructor).match(/^function\s*([^\s(]+)/)
        return matches ? matches[1] : 'anonymous'

    default: return toString.split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

**null** is a special keyword that indicates an absence of value.

think about it as a value, like:

- "foo"  is string,
- true   is boolean ,
- 1234   is number,
- null   is undefined.

---

**undefined** property indicates that a variable has not been assigned a value including null too .
Like

```
var foo;
```

---

*defined empty variable is `null` of datatype `undefined`*

---

Both of them are representing a  **value of a variable with no value**

*AND*
`null` doesn't represent a *string* that has no value - empty string-

---

**Like**

```
var a = ''; 
console.log(typeof a); // string 
console.log(a == null); //false 
console.log(a == undefined); // false
```

Now if

```
var a;
console.log(a == null); //true
console.log(a == undefined); //true
```

**BUT**

```
var a; 
console.log(a === null); //false 
console.log(a === undefined); // true
```

**SO** each one has it own way to use

**undefined** use it to compare the variable data type

**null** use it to empty a value of a variable

```
var a = 'javascript';
a = null ; // will change the type of variable "a" from string to object
```

Comment: null is also a data type. Both undefined and null are data types and values

Comment: `null` Absolutely IS a data type: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx . The fact that `typeof null` returns `object` is a well known and documented bug in early versions of ECMAScript that has remained for backwards-compatibility. The link that *you* actually posted in your comment says halfway down the page "typeof null        // object (bug in ECMAScript, should be null)" ! So please, show some search effort before commenting on down-votes

Comment: Definitions contradict: "absence of value" vs "has not been assigned a value". Isn't it the same?

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Null and undefined are both distinct datatypes. null is of type null and undefined is of type undefined. Only when using a truthy operator (==) may we see that javascript says its true but a strict comparison (===) is produces a false.

Comment: To this day _“null is undefined”_ remains wrong.

Answer (score 27):

**null**: absence of value for a variable; **undefined**: absence of variable itself;

*..where variable is a symbolic name associated with a value.*

JS could be kind enough to implicitly init newly declared variables with **null**, but it does not.

Comment: `var a = {}; a.n = undefined;' then ..`a.hasOwnProperty('n') == true` ...so saying  **absence of variable itself** isn't correct anymore

Comment: That's a really pithy definition, but it's not really accurate - for the reason you give. A defined variable starts with the value `undefined`.

Comment: Even after these many years of this answer being posted, I think I agree with this answer. The intent of `undefined` is that the variable doesn't exist and the intent of `null` is that variable exists but has no value. Peeps are going into the implementation-specific details by checking `typeof` variables but missed to understand one of the most powerful term of CS called "abstraction".

Answer (score 18):

> You might consider undefined to represent a system-level, unexpected, or error-like absence of value and null to represent program-level, normal, or expected absence of value.

via JavaScript:The Definitive Guide

Comment: I really like this description.

Comment: This is what I think I'm going to use as well. If I receive a null I know the value was set to null on purpose

Answer (score 18):

A lot of "technical" answers have been given, all of them mostly correct from the limited point of view of JS as a mere programming language.

However, I would like to add the following thoughts, especially when you're writing TypeScript code as part of a bigger project / (enterprise) application:

- When talking with a Backend of some kind you'll most probably receive JSON
- While some backends correctly avoid the use of "null" in their JSON (removing those properties), others do not
- Now, while "null" **may** mean that the value is missing deliberately, more often it does not convey this meaning. Most databases use "null" just because they don't have an "undefined" type. But the meaning really just is "undefined".
- Because of that, you can never know if a "null" value really means deliberate absence. Therefore "null" cannot really mean the deliberate choice of "missing value". It is undecidable in general.
- As a consequence, **semantically**, "null" and "undefined" are exactly the same thing **in practice**.

Therefore, in an effort to harmonize things I'm strictly against using "null" and want to encourage you to stop using "null" in your code. It's far easier than you might think. Don't get me wrong. I'm not talking about not handling "null" values, only to avoid explicitly using them in your code. Put differently: your code should still be able to work with accidentally passed "null" values coming from outside your application, e.g. via a 3rd party lib like [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42713), or a 3rd party backend.

Here are the guidelines that make it possible:

- **avoid** direct undefined type guards (e.g. `if (value === undefined) { ... }`.
- Instead, use indirect type guards (aka truthiness checks) e.g. `if (value) { ... }`

  - Whenever 0 or empty strings are meaningful, use either

    - an explicit helper method like [Lodash's isNil](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNil)
    - or include the meaningful value in the comparison (e.g. `if (!value && value !== 0) { ... }`)
- Consider using a [lint rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-null-keyword/) that disallows the usage of null

Comment: This is an interesting perspective, and I think it could be expanded; and that's why I'm just posting this comment. Now that C# has implemented non-nullable types, there's a kind of "progress", if you want to call it that, towards understanding something that I'd phrase like: if you request a database for a key that it doesn't have, then you return undefined, because the key is undefined; but if you request a key that it does have, you return null for any value that's not null — you don't return undefined there. So just wondering if fails are picking up on some trend or whatever you call it?

Comment: I agree with this completely. It's more important to look at this in the context of the ecosystem, you generally cannot garuntee your datasource is differentiating between Unknown and Null in the same way that Javascript the programming language does. In fact this is rarely true. Therefore you cannot assume null is intentional for this reason you must treat them same. 

This is especially true when we are discussing a program that gets data from multiple sources or you don't have control of the structure of the datasource. Javascripts actual implementation is unimportant in this context.

Comment: Agree that `if (value)` is better than `if (value == null)`. But what would a function return instead of an object, when it encounters an error? I would think that `return null` is the obvious choice, but it's not clear what you're suggesting with *'stop using "null" in your code*' in this case.

Comment: @Nagev: you need to decide whether you want to handle the error directly in the function or if you would like to have the caller handle it. The latter can be done easily by making your function actually throw an Error. The former can be done by either still returning an object of some kind (with maybe only defaults or empty or undefined properties). Alternatively you can just return `undefined` and make this a valid return value besides objects (e.g. think about TS signature `(): YourType | undefined`). The caller can then easily skip `undefined` via simple truthiness check `if (...) {}`

Comment: They're all good options, thanks for clarifying. I guess it's a matter of preference (unless of course dictated by the code base or team conventions). Personally, I like throwing exceptions sparingly, as I find it annoying having to wrap everything in `try ... catch`. Returning a custom object can be overly complex in many cases. And the `if (...)` test works as well for `undefined` as it does for `null`, and since the latter is actually an object, `null` makes sense when an object is the return type. The function is saying: sorry, can't give you the object you want, here is `null` instead.

Comment: And by the way, using a `null` object will often lead to an exception anyway, so if the intention is to handle it higher up, that also covers it. Although it has the disadvantage of not being a custom/specific exception. If that's desirable, for example handling each case differently, it's one case where I'd prefer to throw exceptions.

Comment: I completely agree with the main sentiment of this post. The difference between `null` and `undefined` is just the opinion of the person who used it in the first place. Looking through some of the other answers here, it is clear that many people have different ideas about what each means. The only way of silencing those ambiguous opinions is to accept that, at a conceptual level, they are the same thing. As such, the safe way to check for both `null` and `undefined` is `if(value == null){...`. Airbnb ESLINT rules specifically make an exception to the "always use `===`" to allow for `== null`.

Answer (score 17):

The best way to understand the difference is to first clear your mind of the inner workings of JavaScript and just understand the differences in meaning between:

```
let supervisor = "None"
    // I have a supervisor named "None"

let supervisor = null
    // I do NOT have a supervisor. It is a FACT that I do not.

let supervisor = undefined
    // I may or may not have a supervisor. I either don't know
    // if I do or not, or I am choosing not to tell you. It is
    // irrelevant or none of your business.
```

There is a difference in meaning between these three cases, and JavaScript distinguishes the latter two cases with two different values, `null` and `undefined`. You are free to use those values explicitly to convey those meanings.

So what are some of the JavaScript-specific issues that arise due to this philosophical basis?

1. A declared variable without an initializer gets the value `undefined` because you never said anything about the what the intended value was.

   ```
   let supervisor;
   assert(supervisor === undefined);
   ```
2. A property of an object that has never been set evaluates to `undefined` because no one ever said anything about that property.

   ```
   const dog = { name: 'Sparky', age: 2 };
   assert(dog.breed === undefined);
   ```
3. `null` and `undefined` are "similar" to each other because Brendan Eich said so. But they are emphatically not equal to each other.

   ```
   assert(null == undefined);
   assert(null !== undefined);
   ```
4. `null` and `undefined` thankfully have different types. `null` belongs to the type `Null` and `undefined` to the type `Undefined`. This is in the spec, but you would never know this because of the `typeof` weirdness which I will not repeat here.
5. A function reaching the end of its body without an explicit return statement returns `undefined` since you don't know anything about what it returned.

By the way, there are other forms of "nothingness" in JavaScript (it's good to have studied Philosophy....)

- `NaN`
- Using a variable that has never been declared and receiving a `ReferenceError`
- Using a `let` or `const` defined local variable in its temporal dead zone and receiving a `ReferenceError`
- Empty cells in sparse arrays. Yes these are not even `undefined` although they compare `===` to undefined.

  ```
  $ node
  > const a = [1, undefined, 2]
  > const b = [1, , 2]
  > a
  [ 1, undefined, 2 ]
  > b
  [ 1, <1 empty item>, 2 ]
  ```

Comment: Best answer! Most of the answers ignore the fact that you can **define the value of a variable as `undefined`**, like in the `let supervisor = undefined` case.

Comment: Thank you, and yes, that misconception that something is `undefined` only if it has not been declared or has not yet been given a value is so rampant and it is really hard to get across to people (though I keep trying). So many people trash JavaScript for having both `null` and `undefined` but these values _do_ have completely distinct meanings and for the most part they work well with their intended meanings (IMHO of course).

Answer (score 15):

`null` is a special value meaning "no value". `null` is a special object because `typeof null` returns 'object'.

On the other hand, `undefined` means that the variable has not been declared, or has not been given a value.

Comment: It is important to note, that while `undefined` may mean that a variable has not been declared, but does not guarantee that. A variable can be declared as `var thing;` and it will be equal to `undefined`.

Answer (score 13):

**null** and **undefined** are two distinct object types which have the following in common:

- both can only hold a single value, **null** and **undefined** respectively;
- both have no properties or methods and an attempt to read any properties of either will result in a run-time error (for all other objects, you get value **undefined** if you try to read a non-existent property);
- values **null** and **undefined** are considered equal to each other and to nothing else by `==` and `!=` operators.

The similarities however end here. For once, there is a fundamental difference in the way how keywords **null** and **undefined** are implemented. This is not obvious, but consider the following example:

```
var undefined = "foo";
WScript.Echo(undefined); // This will print: foo
```

**undefined**, **NaN** and **Infinity** are just names of preinitialized "superglobal" variables - they are initialized at run-time and can be overridden by normal global or local variable with the same names.

Now, let's try the same thing with **null**:

```
var null = "foo"; // This will cause a compile-time error
WScript.Echo(null);
```

Oops! **null**, **true** and **false** are reserved keywords - compiler won't let you use them as variable or property names

Another difference is that **undefined** is a primitive type, while **null** is an object type (indicating the absense of an object reference). Consider the following:

```
WScript.Echo(typeof false); // Will print: boolean
WScript.Echo(typeof 0); // Will print: number
WScript.Echo(typeof ""); // Will print: string
WScript.Echo(typeof {}); // Will print: object
WScript.Echo(typeof undefined); // Will print: undefined
WScript.Echo(typeof null); // (!!!) Will print: object
```

Also, there is an important difference in the way **null** and **undefined** are treated in numeric context:

```
var a; // declared but uninitialized variables hold the value undefined
WScript.Echo(a === undefined); // Prints: -1

var b = null; // the value null must be explicitly assigned 
WScript.Echo(b === null); // Prints: -1

WScript.Echo(a == b); // Prints: -1 (as expected)
WScript.Echo(a >= b); // Prints: 0 (WTF!?)

WScript.Echo(a >= a); // Prints: 0 (!!!???)
WScript.Echo(isNaN(a)); // Prints: -1 (a evaluates to NaN!)
WScript.Echo(1*a); // Prints: -1.#IND (in Echo output this means NaN)

WScript.Echo(b >= b); // Prints: -1 (as expected)
WScript.Echo(isNaN(b)); // Prints: 0 (b evaluates to a valid number)
WScript.Echo(1*b); // Prints: 0 (b evaluates to 0)

WScript.Echo(a >= 0 && a <= 0); // Prints: 0 (as expected)
WScript.Echo(a == 0); // Prints: 0 (as expected)
WScript.Echo(b >= 0 && b <= 0); // Prints: -1 (as expected)
WScript.Echo(b == 0); // Prints: 0 (!!!)
```

**null** becomes **0** when used in arithmetic expressions or numeric comparisons - similarly to **false**, it is basically just a special kind of "zero". **undefined**, on the other hand, is a true "nothing" and becomes **NaN** ("not a number") when you try to use it in numeric context.

Note that **null** and **undefined** receive a special treatment from `==` and `!=` operators, but you can test true numeric equality of **a** and **b** with the expression `(a >= b && a <= b)`.

Answer (score 12):

I'll explain `undefined`, `null` and `Uncaught ReferenceError`:

1 - `Uncaught ReferenceError` : variable **has not been declared** in your script, there is no reference to this varaible 
2 - `undefined`: Variable declared but does not initialised 
3 - `null` : Variable declared and is an empty value

Answer (score 10):

Undefined means a variable has been declared but has no value:

```
var var1;
alert(var1); //undefined
alert(typeof var1); //undefined
```

Null is an assignment:

```
var var2= null;
alert(var2); //null
alert(typeof var2); //object
```

Answer (score 9):

tl;dr

Use `null` for set a variable you know it is an Object.

Use `undefined` for set a variable whose type is mixed.

---

This is my usage of both 5 primitives and Object type, and that explain the difference between « use case » of `undefined` or `null`.

**String**

If you know a variable is only a string while all lifecycle, by convention, you could initialize it, to `""`:

```
("") ? true : false; // false
typeof ""; // "string";
("Hello World") ? true : false; // true
typeof "Hello World"; // "string"
```

**Number**

If you know a variable is only a number while all lifecycle, by convention, you could initialize it, to `0` (or `NaN` if `0` is an important value in your usage):

```
(0) ? true : false; // false
typeof 0; // "number";
(16) ? true : false; // true
typeof 16; // "number"
```

or

```
(NaN) ? true : false; // false
typeof NaN; // "number";
(16) ? true : false; // true
typeof 16; // "number"
```

**Boolean**

If you know a variable is only a boolean while all lifecycle, by convention, you could initialize it, to `false`:

```
(false) ? true : false; // false
typeof false; // "boolean";
(true) ? true : false; // true
typeof true; // "boolean"
```

**Object**

If you know a variable is only an Object while all lifecycle, by convention, you could initialize it, to `null`:

```
(null) ? true : false; // false
typeof null; // "object";
({}) ? true : false; // true
typeof {}; // "object"
```

*Note: the smart usage off null is to be the **falsy** version of an Object because an Object is always `true`, and because `typeof null` return `object`. That means `typeof myVarObject` return consistent value for both Object and null type.*

**All**

If you know a variable has a mixed type (any type while all lifecycle), by convention, you could initialize it, to `undefined`.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to a different meaning there are other differences:

1. **[Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)** works differently for these two values:

   ```js
   const { a = "default" } = { a: undefined }; // a is "default"
   const { b = "default" } = { b: null };      // b is null
   ```
2. **JSON.stringify()** keeps `null` but omits `undefined`

   ```js
   const json = JSON.stringify({ undefinedValue: undefined, nullValue: null });
   console.log(json); // prints {"nullValue":null}
   ```
3. **typeof operator**

   ```js
   console.log(typeof undefined); // "undefined"
   console.log(typeof null);      // "object" instead of "null"
   ```

Answer (score 8):

In JavasScript there are 5 primitive data types: String, Number, Boolean, null and undefined.
I will try to explain with some simple examples.

Let's say we have a simple function

```
 function test(a) {
     if(a == null) {
        alert("a is null");
     } else {
        alert("The value of a is " + a);
     }
  }
```

Also, in above `function if(a == null)` is the same as `if(!a)`.

Now when we call this function without passing the parameter a

```
test(); // will alert "a is null";
test(4); // will alert "The value of a is " + 4;
```

also

```
var a;
alert(typeof a);
```

This will give undefined; we have declared a variable but we have not asigned any value to this variable;

but if we write

```
var a = null;
alert(typeof a); // will give alert as object
```

so null is an object. In a way we have assigned a value null to 'a'

Comment: Symbol is a new primitive type :)

Comment: In your `a == null` example above, it's only true because `null` and `undefined` are both truthily equal (`null === undefined` is false.) If you call `test()` without an argument, it will be `undefined`.

Comment: Update for 2020: There are now _seven_ primitives types. Symbol and BigInt were added since this answer was written.

Comment: Nitpick: `String` and `Number` are complex types: they have `Object` as their `prototype`. The primitive types return `string` and `number` from the `typeof` command. e.g `typeof 'foo'; // => "string"` and `typeof (new String('foo')); // => "object"`.

Answer (score 6):

OK, we may get confused when we hear about `null` and `undefined`, but let's start it simple, they both are **falsy** and similar in many ways, but weird part of JavaScript, make them a couple of significant differences, for example, **typeof** `null` is `'object'` while **typeof** `undefined` is `'undefined'`.

```
typeof null; //"object"
typeof undefined; //"undefined";
```

But if you check them with `==` as below, you see they are both **falsy**:

```
null==undefined; //true
```

Also you can assign `null` to an object property or to a primitive, while `undefined` can simply be achieved by not assigning to anything.

I create a quick image to show the differences for you at a glance.

[image: Null and Undefined]

Answer (score 6):

When you declare a variable in javascript, it is assigned the value `undefined`. This means the variable is untouched and can be assigned any value in future. It also implies that you don't know the value that this variable is going to hold at the time of declaration.

Now you can explicitly assign a variable `null`. It means that the variable does not have any value. For example - Some people don't have a middle name. So in such a case its better to assign the value null to the middlename variable of a person object.

Now suppose that someone is accessing the middlename variable of your person object and it has the value `undefined`. He wouldn't know if the developer forgot to initialize this variable or if it didn't have any value. If it has the value `null`, then the user can easily infer that middlename doesn't have any value and it is not an untouched variable.

Answer (score 5):

For the `undefined` type, there is one and only one value: `undefined`.

For the `null` type, there is one and only one value: `null`.

So for both of them, **the label is both its type and its value.**

The difference between them. For example:

- `null` is an empty value
- `undefined` is a missing value

Or:

- `undefined` hasn't had a value yet
- `null` had a value and doesn't anymore

Actually, `null` is a **special keyword**, not an identifier, and thus you cannot treat it as a variable to assign to.

However, `undefined` is an **identifier**. In both `non-strict` mode and `strict` mode, however, you can create a local variable of the name undefined. But this is one terrible idea!

```
function foo() {
    undefined = 2; // bad idea!
}

foo();

function foo() {
    "use strict";
    undefined = 2; // TypeError!
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 5):

I want to add a knowledge point which pertains to a subtle difference between **null** and **undefined**. This is good to know when you are trying to learn Vanilla JavaScript(JS) from ground up:

> **null** is a reserved keyword in JS while **undefined** is a property on
> the global object of the run-time environment you're in.

While writing code, this difference is not identifiable as both **null** and **undefined** are always used in right hand side (RHS) of a JavaScript statement. But when you use them in left hand side (LHS) of an expression then you can observe this difference easily. So JS interpreter interprets the below code as error:

```
var null = 'foo'
```

It gives below error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token null

At the same time, below code runs successfully although I won't recommend doing so in real life:

```
var undefined = 'bar'
```

This works because **undefined** is a property on the global object ([window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object in case of JavaScript running in a browser)

Comment: `undefined='bar'` does not really assign any value to `undefined` (which is immutable), it just doesn't throw an error confusingly.

Answer (score 4):

null and undefined are both are used to represent the absence of some value.

```
var a = null;
```

a is initialized and defined.

```
typeof(a)
//object
```

null is an object in JavaScript

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(a) // [object Object]

var b;
```

b is undefined and uninitialized

undefined object properties are also undefined. For example "x" is not defined on object c and if you try to access c.x, it will return undefined.

Generally we assign null to variables not undefined.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(null); // "[object Null]"`

Answer (score 4):

Per Ryan Morr's thorough article on this subject...

"Generally, if you need to assign a non-value to a variable or property, pass it to a function, or return it from a function, null is almost always the best option. To put it simply, JavaScript uses undefined and programmers should use null."

See [Exploring the Eternal Abyss of Null and Undefined](http://ryanmorr.com/exploring-the-eternal-abyss-of-null-and-undefined/)

Answer (score 4):

In javascript all variables are stored as key value pairs.  Each variable is stored as *variable_name : variable_value/reference*.

**undefined** means a variable has been given a space in memory, but no value is assigned to it.  As a best practice, you should not use this type as an assignment.

In that case how to denote when you want a variable to be without value at a later point in the code?  You can use the type
**null** ,which is also a type that is used to define the same thing, absence of a value, but it is not the same as undefined, as in this case you actually have the value in memory.  That value is *null*

Both are similar but usage and meaning are different.

Answer (score 4):

> The difference in meaning between undefined and null is an accident of JavaScript’s design, and it doesn’t matter most of the time. In cases where you actually have to concern yourself with these values, I recommend treating them as mostly interchangeable.

From the [Eloquent Javascript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html#h_FewqJ8K2E+) book

Answer (score 3):

As typeof returns undefined, undefined is a type where as null is an initializer indicates the variable points to no object(virtually everything in Javascript is an object).

Answer (score 3):

**null** - It is an assignment value, which is used with variable to represent no value (it's an object).

**undefined** - It is a variable which does not have any value assigned to it, so JavaScript will assign an undefined to it (it's a data type).

**undeclared** - If a variable is not created at all, it is known as undeclared.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out. The output is worth thousand words.

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");

checkif("1, no argument"                        );
checkif("2, undefined explicitly",     undefined);
checkif("3, null explicitly",               null);
checkif("4, the 0",                            0);
checkif("5, empty string",                    '');
checkif("6, string",                    "string");
checkif("7, number",                      123456);

function checkif (a1, a2) {
 print("\ncheckif(), " + a1 + ":");
 if (a2 == undefined) {
  print("==undefined:    YES");
 } else {
  print("==undefined:    NO");
 }
 if (a2 === undefined) {
  print("===undefined:   YES");
 } else {
  print("===undefined:   NO");
 }
 if (a2 == null) {
  print("==null:         YES");
 } else {
  print("==null:         NO");
 }
 if (a2 === null) {
  print("===null:        YES");
 } else {
  print("===null:        NO");
 }
 if (a2 == '') {
  print("=='':           YES");
 } else {
  print("=='':           NO");
 }
 if (a2 === '') {
  print("==='':          YES");
 } else {
  print("==='':          NO");
 }
 if (isNaN(a2)) {
  print("isNaN():        YES");
 } else {
  print("isNaN():        NO");
 }
 if (a2) {
  print("if-?:           YES");
 } else {
  print("if-?:           NO");
 }
  print("typeof():       " + typeof(a2));
}

function print(v) {
 b1.innerHTML += v + "\n";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<pre id="b1"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Cheers!

Comment: From this I actually learned that `isNaN(null)` returns `false` - which surprised me.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `undefined` and `null` is minimal, but there is a difference. A variable whose value is `undefined` has never been initialized. A variable whose value is `null` was explicitly given a value of `null`, which means that the variable was explicitly set to have no value. If you compare `undefined` and `null` by using the `null==undefined` expression, they will be equal.

Comment: This answer is misleading... see the discussion in the accepted answer. Bottom line - `null==undefined` is `true` only because of implicit casting (or the equivalent term in JS). Evidently, `null===undefined` is `false` because using when you use `===` it compares the **type** as well.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, **Undefined** is a global variable that javascript create at the run time whether null means that no value has assigned to the variable (actually null is itself an object).

Let's take an example:

```
        var x;  //we declared a variable x, but no value has been assigned to it.
        document.write(x) //let's print the variable x
```

**Undefined** that's what you will get as output.

Now,

```
        x=5;
        y=null;
        z=x+y;
```

and you will get **5** as output. That's the main difference between the **Undefined** and **null**

Answer (score 2):

Both special values imply an empty state.

The main difference is that **undefined** represents the value of a variable that wasn’t yet initialized, while **null** represents an intentional absence of an object.

> The variable number is defined, however, is not assigned with an initial value:

```
let number;
number; // => undefined
```

> number variable is undefined, which clearly indicates an uninitialized variable
>
> The same uninitialized concept happens when a non-existing object property is accessed:

```
const obj = { firstName: 'Dmitri' };
obj.lastName; // => undefined
```

> Because lastName property does not exist in obj, JavaScript correctly evaluates obj.lastName to undefined.

In other cases, you know that a variable expects to hold an object or a function to return an object. But for some reason, you can’t instantiate the object. In such a case null is a meaningful indicator of a missing object.

For example, clone() is a function that clones a plain JavaScript object. The function is expected to return an object:

```
function clone(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
    return Object.assign({}, obj);
  }
  return null;
}
clone({name: 'John'}); // => {name: 'John'}
clone(15);             // => null
clone(null);           // => null
```

However, clone() might be invoked with a non-object argument: 15 or null (or generally a primitive value, null or undefined). In such case, the function cannot create a clone, so it returns null - the indicator of a missing object.

> **typeof** operator makes the distinction between the two values:

```
typeof undefined; // => 'undefined'
typeof null;      // => 'object'
```

> The strict quality operator **===** correctly differentiates undefined from null:

```
let nothing = undefined;
let missingObject = null;
nothing === missingObject; // => false
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote from "Eloquent Javascript" 3rd edition by Marijn Haverbeke:

> The difference in meaning between `undefined` and `null` is an accident of Javascript's design, and it doesn't matter most of the time. In cases where you actually have to concern yourself with these values, I recommend treating them as mostly interchangeable

Honestly, at first, I am a bit skeptical about this advice. However, in my own interpretation, it is a `lazy` (vs `eager`) way to deal with their differences. Maybe, we don't have to deal with the differences at all. If we have to, we can delay our concern (util we have to) and not `hyperactively/defensively` worry about it every step of the way as those values (`null` and `undefined`) flow through our code.

PS: This is not a direct answer to your question. This is just a related opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Generally – don't use `null` to avoid confusion.

1. Standard library methods return `undefined`, not `null`

```js
let a = [10];
console.log(a[1]) //=> undefined
console.log(a.find(value => value === 5)) //=> undefined
```

2. I see often in people's code that some variable was `undefined` at first, then assigned to some value, then cleared by setting to `null`. That's not consistent, better to set back to `undefined`.

Still, `null` makes sense if framework uses it, or for json serialization.

Answer (score 1):

also note the difference in comparison:

```
10 > undefined
false

10 < undefined
false

10 < null
false

10 > null
true
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of null is Object, while the type of undefined is undefined.
Null means ‘no value’, while undefined means ‘not existing’.

```
typeof undefined; //undefined
typeof null; // Object
undefined !== null; //true
undefined == null; //true
undefined === null; //false
var var1;
var1; //undefined 
var var2 = null;
var2; //null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data  = { banners: null }
const { banners = [] } = data;
console.log(data)      // null


const data  = { banners: undefined }
const { banners = [] } = data;
console.log(data)      // []
```

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript null is an empty or non-existent value and it must be assigned. But Undefined means a variable has been declared, but not value has not been defined.

```
let a = null;  
console.log(a);    // null
let b;         
console.log(b);    // undefined
```

In JS both null and undefined are primitive values. Also you can look the following lines of code

```
console.log(typeof null); //Object
console.log(typeof undefined); //undefined
console.log(10+null); // 10
console.log(10+undefined); //NaN
```

Comment: Undeclared variables have also undefined type. And typeof undefined is "undefined", not "object".

Answer (score -2):

If a variable is not initialized then it is undefined.
undefined is not a object.
Example:  var MyName;
          console.log(typeof MyName);

Check the console log in development tool, it will be printed as undefined.

null is a a object.If you want some variable to be null then null is used.null variable exists but value is not known.It should be assigned to a variable pro grammatically.  null is not automatically initialized.

Example : var MyName = null;
          console.log(typeof MyName);
Check the csole log in development tool, it will be an object.

Answer (score -4):

Just to add my views -

A variable that is declared only, and never used anywhere, is removed off by an optimizing compiler in case of compiled languages like C++[or a warning is flagged in the IDE]. It ultimately means that the variable is non-existent because it's memory is never allocated.

In case of javascript interpreter, [I guess] a variable is treated as existing only from the point onwards where it is given a value. Before that point, it's type is "undefined", and no memory is allocated for it. And, so its type is undefined.

A null in javascript *is* a value that represents an address, but that address points to nothing yet[non-existent reference]. Nevertheless, its a value.

Comment: Nope, there needs to be some memory allocated to differentiate a declared (yet `undefined`) variable from a non-declared one. `undefined` is just a value as well, and it's the default value for uninitialized variables.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge about how the js interpreter might be working, but the guess was based on the fact that the typeof operator applied to a non-existant variable and a declared-only variable yields the same "undefined" string. I have doubts about the fact that an undeclared variable gets a default primitive value undefined[perhaps, somebody who has internal knowldege of the interpreter could clarify this], even though the comparison would return true. There was no undefined value prior to ECMA-262?

Comment: That `typeof` has the same output for these two cases doesn't mean anything (though it might hint at the original implementation in netscape). Admittedly, it's possible that an optimizing compiler doesn't allocate stack variables until they're assigned to, but I don't think the non-optimising ones of the various implementations (note: there isn't a single interpreter for the language) do this - after all, ES spec says variable environments are initialized on call.

Comment: After a research I find my views were not correct. Please refer section 12.2 ECMA Standard - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2 Quote: A variable statement declares variables that are created as defined in 10.5. Variables are initialised to undefined when created. And, on the following link, the point no. 2 clarifies that undeclared variables are in fact created only at the time of initialization, otherwise not - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score -4):

Null is ALWAYS an unknown object that exists in memory, whereas undefined is not.