# How do I check for null values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null, compare, comparison, equality

How can I check for null values in JavaScript? I wrote the code below but it didn't work.

```js
if (pass == null || cpass == null || email == null || cemail == null || user == null) {
  alert("fill all columns");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the values you are testing are actually null and not just empty string?

Comment: testing `null` in js should be done with the strict operator `===`

Comment: @Hogan, I meant strict, and I assume by the upvotes that the readers interpreted it that way...

Comment: @davin - true, but not the problem here since if it were the statement would still work.

Comment: @cwolves, if I thought it were the problem I would have made that comment an answer. Check out my wording, I'm clearly making a general statement about the language in reference to the OP's practise, and not proposing that this solves his problem.

Comment: @ic3b3rg I *think* I agree with your rollbacks, but I'd be happier if you explained them.

Comment: @TRiG the proposed changes fundamentally alter the nature of the question to the point where the answers (not just mine) lose context and don't make sense. The edit should just be a comment.

Answer (score 1062, accepted):

JavaScript is very flexible with regards to checking for "null" values.  I'm guessing you're actually looking for empty strings, in which case this simpler code will work:

```
if(!pass || !cpass || !email || !cemail || !user){
```

Which will check for empty strings (`""`), `null`, `undefined`, `false` and the numbers `0` and `NaN`.

Please note that if you are specifically checking for numbers, it is a common mistake to miss `0` with this method, and `num !== 0` is preferred (or `num !== -1` or `~num` (hacky code that also checks against `-1`)) for functions that return `-1`, e.g. `indexOf`).

Comment: It would be very useful to know which parts of this test for which values. Sometimes you're looking for one in particular.

Comment: Somewhat of a late statement, but yes, you can perform test against each one @inorganik , see my answer below

Comment: Readers, please be careful when using this type of test on numeric data.  Do not use `!` or `!!` to test for `null` or `undefined` on typically-numeric data unless you also want to throw away values of 0.

Comment: Have to agree with NickS. If you're specifically testing for null, it's possible to get false positives with this type of boolean NOT test. This is an overbroad solution to a specific question.

Comment: The answer itself states this: "...and the numbers `0`...".  I believe this answer is perfectly appropriate for the question as given the context (which I'm inferring is "username, password, email"), they're not checking for `0` values.  Given the popularity of this question and answer, however, I agree that it's worth mentioning in the answer itself.

Comment: @zyklus Even if he is asking about usernames and passwords, it's possible that functions could be gathering the data from the forms and returning null if an empty string is found. But much more importantly, Stack Overflow questions come up as google results all the time, so many people who are curious how to check for a null value will be directed here and will see your answer first. It probably would have been best to answer the question that was asked and then address the specifics of this code. Sorry if that upsets you, SO asks me to comment when I downvote an answer so I am doing that.

Comment: @Hendeca - The context of answering a question for the 420,000 people that have seen this question is _very_ different than the context of answering it for the OP.  I'll consider re-wording the answer.

Answer (score 705):

To check for null **SPECIFICALLY** you would use this:

```
if (variable === null)
```

This test will **ONLY** pass for `null` and will not pass for `""`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, or `NaN`.

Additionally, I've provided absolute checks for each "false-like" value (one that would return true for `!variable`).

Note, for some of the absolute checks, you will need to implement use of the `absolutely equals: ===` and `typeof`.

[I've created a **JSFiddle** here to show all of the individual tests working](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/8n9vtyek/)

Here is the output of each check:

```
Null Test:

if (variable === null)

- variable = ""; (false) typeof variable = string

- variable = null; (true) typeof variable = object

- variable = undefined; (false) typeof variable = undefined

- variable = false; (false) typeof variable = boolean

- variable = 0; (false) typeof variable = number

- variable = NaN; (false) typeof variable = number



Empty String Test:

if (variable === '')

- variable = ''; (true) typeof variable = string

- variable = null; (false) typeof variable = object

- variable = undefined; (false) typeof variable = undefined

- variable = false; (false) typeof variable = boolean

- variable = 0; (false) typeof variable = number

- variable = NaN; (false) typeof variable = number




Undefined Test:

if (typeof variable == "undefined")

-- or --

if (variable === undefined)

- variable = ''; (false) typeof variable = string

- variable = null; (false) typeof variable = object

- variable = undefined; (true) typeof variable = undefined

- variable = false; (false) typeof variable = boolean

- variable = 0; (false) typeof variable = number

- variable = NaN; (false) typeof variable = number



False Test:

if (variable === false)

- variable = ''; (false) typeof variable = string

- variable = null; (false) typeof variable = object

- variable = undefined; (false) typeof variable = undefined

- variable = false; (true) typeof variable = boolean

- variable = 0; (false) typeof variable = number

- variable = NaN; (false) typeof variable = number



Zero Test:

if (variable === 0)

- variable = ''; (false) typeof variable = string

- variable = null; (false) typeof variable = object

- variable = undefined; (false) typeof variable = undefined

- variable = false; (false) typeof variable = boolean

- variable = 0; (true) typeof variable = number

- variable = NaN; (false) typeof variable = number



NaN Test:

if (typeof variable == 'number' && !parseFloat(variable) && variable !== 0)

-- or --

if (isNaN(variable))

- variable = ''; (false) typeof variable = string

- variable = null; (false) typeof variable = object

- variable = undefined; (false) typeof variable = undefined

- variable = false; (false) typeof variable = boolean

- variable = 0; (false) typeof variable = number

- variable = NaN; (true) typeof variable = number
```

As you can see, it's a little more difficult to test against `NaN`;

Comment: What is the purpose of type checking if you use `===` strict equality? Thanks.

Also for NaN test you can use `isNaN(value)` that will return `true` only if variable equals NaN.

Comment: Is there a case where `variable === null` but is not of type "object"? If there is not, why not simplify the check to `variable === null`, throwing out the second conjunct? Thanks.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Good question, and honestly, no, I do not think that there is. You are most likely safe enough using `variable === null` which I just tested [here in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/8n9vtyek/6/). The reason I also used ` && typeof variable === 'object'` was not only to illustrate the interesting fact that a `null` value is a typeof `object`, but also to keep with the flow of the other checks. But yes, in conclusion, you are safe to use simply `variable === null`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/avt1cgem/1/ Here is this answer broken out into functions. Not very usefull, but I did it anyways.

Comment: I'm going to do something that is almost never a good idea: change the code in this answer. Specifically, remove the totally unnecessary test for type object, when checking for null. This is a ***fundamental*** code snippet: not a good idea to have *even a single beginner* mis-learn that they need to do that verbose test.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yea,  I think it's time to remove that, and to possibly clean this up. It is not necessary as part of the test, but was provided to note that `null` is `typeof Object`. It should be a comment instead. +1

Comment: Readers: Disregard my previous statements about `isNaN`. This is a perfectly fine way to test for the existence of `NaN` in JavaScript.

Comment: Let me share a very interesting review I found about how `null` was erroneously typed as `object`: https://alexanderell.is/posts/typeof-null/

Answer (score 75):

just replace the `==` with `===` in all places.

`==` is a loose or abstract equality comparison

`===` is a strict equality comparison

See the MDN article on [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for more detail.

Comment: This only works if you consider `undefined` to be not `null`. Otherwise it will lead to a lot of unexpected behavior. Generally if you're interested in both `null`/`undefined` but not falsy values, then use `==` (one of the few cases when you should do so).

Comment: @AndrewMao `undefined` **is not** `null`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5076962/753237

Comment: I believe that's what @AndrewMao was saying, really.  His first sentence might be rewritten "This only works in situations where undefined and null are not practical equivalents."

Comment: @BobRodes Thanks for clarifying my poor writing, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @AndrewMao You are very welcome.  And I wouldn't call your writing poor, personally; I'd say it's a good deal better than average.  :)

Answer (score 57):

You can check if some value is null as follows

```
[pass,cpass,email,cemail,user].some(x=> x===null)
```

```js
let pass=1;
let cpass=2;
let email=3;
let cemail=null;
let user=5;

if ( [pass,cpass,email,cemail,user].some(x=> x===null) ) {     
    alert("fill all columns");
    //return false;  
}
```

BONUS: Why `===` is more clear than `==` ([source](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/))

#### a == b

[image]

#### a === b

[image]

Comment: great 2 diagrams, I took the liberty of merging them both: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1o4_lJbSaDNNuVBXyVXds3UIEkjz9Znnwqwc38VLDifI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In addition to the 2 diagrams above. While `if ([] == false)` is true (as shown in your diagram),  `if ([])` also evaluates to true.

Comment: In fact, they now have a merged table at https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/unified/

Answer (score 47):

**Strict equality operator:-**

We can check null by `===`

```
if ( value === null ){

}
```

Just by using `if`

```
if( value ) {

}
```

will evaluate to true if **value is not**:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- false
- 0

Answer (score 19):

At first sight, it looks like a simple trade-off **between coverage and strictness**.

- `==` covers multiple values, can handle more scenarios in less code.
- `===` is the most strict, and that makes it predictable.

Predictability always wins, and that appears to make `===` a one-fits-all solution.

[image]

But it is **wrong**. Even though `===` is predictable, it does **not always** result in predictable code, because it overlooks scenarios.

```
const options = { };
if (options.callback !== null) {
  options.callback();      // error --> callback is undefined.
}
```

**In general** `==` does a more predictable job for null checks:

- In general, `null` and `undefined` both mean the same thing: *"something's missing"*. For predictability, you need to check both values. And then `== null` does a perfect job, because it covers exactly those 2 values. (*i.e. `== null` is equivalent to `=== null && === undefined`*)
- In exceptional cases you **do** want a clear **distinction** between `null` and `undefined`. And in those cases you're better of with a strict `=== undefined` or `=== null`. *(e.g. a distinction between missing/ignore/skip and empty/clear/remove.)* But it is **rare**.

It is not only rare, it's something to avoid. You can't store `undefined` in a traditional database. And you shouldn't rely on `undefined` values in your API designs neither, due to interopability reasons. But even when you don't make a distinction at all, **you can't assume that `undefined` won't happen.** People all around us indirectly take actions that generalize `null`/`undefined` (*which is why questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003424/should-json-include-null-values) are closed as "opinionated".*).

So, to get back to your question. There's nothing wrong with using `== null`. It does exactly what it should do.

```
// FIX 1 --> yes === is very explicit
const options = { };
if (options.callback !== null && 
    options.callback !== undefined) {
  options.callback();
}


// FIX 2 --> but == covers both
const options = { };
if (options.callback != null) {
  options.callback();
}

// FIX 3 --> optional chaining also covers both.
const options = { };
options.callback?.();
```

Answer (score 12):

Improvement over the accepted answer by explicitly checking for `null` but with a simplified syntax:

```
if ([pass, cpass, email, cemail, user].every(x=>x!==null)) {
    // your code here ...
}
```

```js
// Test
let pass=1, cpass=1, email=1, cemail=1, user=1; // just to test

if ([pass, cpass, email, cemail, user].every(x=>x!==null)) {
    // your code here ...
    console.log ("Yayy! None of them are null");
} else {
    console.log ("Oops! At-lease one of them is null");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, you have a return statement without a function body. Chances are that that will throw an error.

A cleaner way to do your check would be to simply use the ! operator:

```
if (!pass || !cpass || !email || !cemail || !user) {

    alert("fill all columns");

}
```

Comment: That code is probably in a function, he just didn't show it ;)

Answer (score 6):

you can use try catch finally

```
 try {
     document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = 'Success' //assuming "mydiv" is undefined
 } catch (e) {

     if (e.name.toString() == "TypeError") //evals to true in this case
     //do something

 } finally {}
```

you can also `throw` your own errors. See [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch2.shtml).

Comment: i think this qualifies as 'paranoid' code.  if you really wrote something like this, it would be with an understanding that "mydiv" couldn't possibly not exist.  we shouldn't reach this code unless we're confident that's the case, and we'd have plenty of avenues such as response codes to make sure we're confident before attempting such a line.

Comment: Do not use try and catch for flow of control. This is not a good solution.

Comment: Up voting since this solution that was perfect for me to manipulate dynamically built DOM in four steps and on each step existed different set of elements. `try {} catch {}` solution prevent the script from error state on non existing elements and beautifully passed through and did the job. Thanks for the idea,  @DrStrangeLove

Answer (score 5):

to check for **undefined** and **null** in javascript you need just to write the following :

```
if (!var) {
        console.log("var IS null or undefined");
} else {
        console.log("var is NOT null or undefined");
}
```

Comment: !var is true with 0, "", NaN, and false, too.

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, no string is equal to `null`.

Maybe you expected `pass == null` to be true when `pass` is an empty string because you're aware that the loose equality operator `==` performs certain kinds of type coercion.

For example, this expression is true:

```
'' == 0
```

In contrast, the strict equality operator `===` says that this is false:

```
'' === 0
```

Given that `''` and `0` are loosely equal, you might reasonably conjecture that `''` and `null` are loosely equal. However, they are not.

This expression is false:

```
'' == null
```

The result of comparing any string to `null` is false. Therefore, `pass == null` and all your other tests are always false, and the user never gets the alert.

To fix your code, compare each value to the empty string:

```
pass === ''
```

If you're certain that `pass` is a string, `pass == ''` will also work because only an empty string is loosely equal to the empty string. On the other hand, some experts say that it's a good practice to always use strict equality in JavaScript unless you specifically want to do the type coercion that the loose equality operator performs.

If you want to know what pairs of values are loosely equal, see the table "Sameness comparisons" in the [Mozilla article on this topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Answer (score 5):

Actually I think you may need to use
`if (value !== null && value !== undefined)`
because if you use `if (value)` you may also filter 0 or false values.

Consider these two functions:

```
const firstTest = value => {
    if (value) {
        console.log('passed');
    } else {
        console.log('failed');
    }
}
const secondTest = value => {
    if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
        console.log('passed');
    } else {
        console.log('failed');
    }
}

firstTest(0);            // result: failed
secondTest(0);           // result: passed

firstTest(false);        // result: failed
secondTest(false);       // result: passed

firstTest('');           // result: failed
secondTest('');          // result: passed

firstTest(null);         // result: failed
secondTest(null);        // result: failed

firstTest(undefined);    // result: failed
secondTest(undefined);   // result: failed
```

In my situation, I just needed to check if the value is null and undefined and I did not want to filter `0` or `false` or `''` values. so I used the second test, but you may need to filter them too which may cause you to use first test.

Comment: `value !== null || value !== undefined` is always true. I think you meant `value !== null && value !== undefined`. That's actually the same as `value != null` (which checks exactly for null and undefined.)

Comment: @bvdb Sorry, in the code I used the correct expression, but up there I forgot :-D I fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The '`Object.is()`' method can be used to determine if two values are the same value. So, you can use it to check whether the object is null or not.

**Check for null values**

```js
let testA = null; //null
//console.log(Object.is(testA, null)); //true //null === null

if(Object.is(testA, null)) {
  console.log("This is a Null Value");
}
```

```
Output:
This is a Null Value
```

```js
let x = null;
if (x === null) {
  console.log("x is null");
}
```

```
Output:
x is null
```

**Check for undefined values** (A variable has been declared, but a value has not been assigned.)

```js
let testB; //undefined
//console.log(Object.is(testB, undefined)); //true //undefined === undefined

if(Object.is(testB, undefined)) {
  console.log("This is an undefined Value");
}
```

```
Output:
This is an undefined Value
```

If the object has not been declared, this cannot be used. As an alternative, you may try this:

```js
if (typeof x === "undefined") {
  console.log("x is undefined");
}
```

```
Output:
The value is either undefined or null
```

---

Mozilla Object.is():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: Note by  "undefined" here you mean that the variable is created/initialized but a value is just not assigned to it. "Undefined" typically means that the variable doesn't exist at all, and in that case your code wouldn't be applicable.

Answer (score 4):

This is a comment on WebWanderer's solution regarding checking for NaN (I don't have enough rep yet to leave a formal comment).  The solution reads as

```
if(!parseInt(variable) && variable != 0 && typeof variable === "number")
```

but this will fail for rational numbers which would round to `0`, such as `variable = 0.1`.  A better test would be:

```
if(isNaN(variable) && typeof variable === "number")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug Gabriel, I've put the fix into my answer. Aside from that, I was able to fix the test by changing `parseInt` to `parseFloat`  (which should have been obvious to me in the first place). I avoided using the `isNan` function because I feel as if many developers view functions such as `isNaN` as some sort of "magic box" that values go into and booleans come out of, and I wanted to should the test a little more in depth. But yes, your suggested test will work and is perfectly fine to use. Sorry I didn't notice your post until now.

Comment: Great, that seems to work.  Thanks for the comment on why you avoided `isNaN` as well, I can get behind that logic.  There's also the Underscore.js method, which seems even more confusing/blackbox, but worth noting anyway because it takes advantage of `NaN !== NaN`.
`Object.prototype.toString.call(variable) === '[object Number]' && variable !== +variable`

Answer (score 4):

You can use lodash module to check value is null or undefined

```
_.isNil(value)
Example 

 country= "Abc"
    _.isNil(country)
    //false

   state= null
    _.isNil(state)
    //true

city= undefined
    _.isNil(state)
    //true

   pin= true
    _.isNil(pin)
    // false
```

Reference link: https://lodash.com/docs/#isNil

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK in **JAVASCRIPT** when a variable is **declared** but has not assigned value, its type is `undefined`. so we can check variable even if it would be an `object` holding some **instance** in place of **value**.

create a helper method for checking nullity that returns `true` and use it in your API.

**helper function to check if variable is empty:**

```
function isEmpty(item){
    if(item){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

**try-catch exceptional API call:**

```
try {

    var pass, cpass, email, cemail, user; // only declared but contains nothing.

    // parametrs checking
    if(isEmpty(pass) || isEmpty(cpass) || isEmpty(email) || isEmpty(cemail) || isEmpty(user)){
        console.log("One or More of these parameter contains no vlaue. [pass] and-or [cpass] and-or [email] and-or [cemail] and-or [user]");
    }else{
        // do stuff
    }

} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
        console.log(e.message); // debugging purpose
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log(e.message); // debugging purpose
        return true;
    }
}
```

**some test cases:**

```
var item = ""; // isEmpty? true
var item = " "; // isEmpty? false
var item; // isEmpty? true
var item = 0; // isEmpty? true
var item = 1; // isEmpty? false
var item = "AAAAA"; // isEmpty? false
var item = NaN; // isEmpty? true
var item = null; // isEmpty? true
var item = undefined; // isEmpty? true

console.log("isEmpty? "+isEmpty(item));
```

Comment: What? This answer has nothing to do with this post. Did you post this answer on this thread by accident?

Comment: This `isEmpty` function behaves exactly like `!`. No need to invent a function. Just do `if (!pass || !cpass || !email ...)`. (Which is already shown in the accepted answer.)  And per WebWanderer's comment, the middle part of this post, "try-catch exceptional API call", does not appear to be relevant to this question. Please explain your intent - when is that useful? How does that relate to the question?

Answer (score 2):

I found a another way to test if the value is null:

```
if(variable >= 0 && typeof variable === "object")
```

`null` acts as a `number` and `object` at the same time. Comparing `null >= 0` or `null <= 0` results in `true`. Comparing `null === 0` or `null > 0` or `null < 0` will result in false. But as `null` is also an object we can detect it as a null.

I made a more complex function **natureof** witch will do better than typeof and can be told what types to include or keep grouped

```js
/* function natureof(variable, [included types])
included types are 
    null - null will result in "undefined" or if included, will result in "null"
    NaN - NaN will result in "undefined" or if included, will result in "NaN"
    -infinity - will separate negative -Inifity from "Infinity"
    number - will split number into "int" or "double"
    array - will separate "array" from "object"
    empty - empty "string" will result in "empty" or
    empty=undefined - empty "string" will result in "undefined"
*/
function natureof(v, ...types){
/*null*/            if(v === null) return types.includes('null') ? "null" : "undefined";
/*NaN*/             if(typeof v == "number") return (isNaN(v)) ? types.includes('NaN') ? "NaN" : "undefined" : 
/*-infinity*/       (v+1 === v) ? (types.includes('-infinity') && v === Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) ? "-infinity" : "infinity" : 
/*number*/          (types.includes('number')) ? (Number.isInteger(v)) ? "int" : "double" : "number";
/*array*/           if(typeof v == "object") return (types.includes('array') && Array.isArray(v)) ? "array" : "object";
/*empty*/           if(typeof v == "string") return (v == "") ? types.includes('empty') ? "empty" : 
/*empty=undefined*/ types.includes('empty=undefined') ? "undefined" : "string" : "string";
                    else return typeof v
}

// DEMO
let types = [null, "", "string", undefined, NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, false, "false", true, "true", 0, 1, -1, 0.1, "test", {var:1}, [1,2], {0: 1, 1: 2, length: 2}]

for(i in types){
console.log("natureof ", types[i], " = ", natureof(types[i], "null", "NaN", "-infinity", "number", "array", "empty=undefined")) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this very simple function that works wonders:

```
function safeOrZero(route) {
  try {
    Function(`return (${route})`)();
  } catch (error) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Function(`return (${route})`)();
}
```

The route is whatever chain of values that can blow up. I use it for jQuery/cheerio and objects and such.

Examples 1: a simple object such as this `const testObj = {items: [{ val: 'haya' }, { val: null }, { val: 'hum!' }];};`.

But it could be a very large object that we haven't even made. So I pass it through:

```
let value1 = testobj.items[2].val;  // "hum!"
let value2 = testobj.items[3].val;  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

let svalue1 = safeOrZero(`testobj.items[2].val`)  // "hum!"
let svalue2 = safeOrZero(`testobj.items[3].val`)  // 0
```

Of course if you prefer you can use `null` or `'No value'`... Whatever suit your needs.

Usually a DOM query or a jQuery selector may throw an error if it's not found. But using something like:

```
const bookLink = safeOrZero($('span.guidebook > a')[0].href);
if(bookLink){
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple Solution for empty values:

```
function isEmpty(value) {
        return (
            value === null || value === undefined || value === '' ||
            (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) ||
            (!(value instanceof Date) && typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length === 0)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very non-human code. But works:

```
if((pass, cpass, email, cemail, user !== null)){
```

Just try it out and help the answer

Comment: it is simple and it works , so `if (xxxx==null) {xxxx'}`

Answer (score 1):

What about optional check with operator ?

for example:

```
// check mother for null or undefined and 
// then if mother exist check her children also
// this 100% sure it support and valid in JS today.
// Apart of that C# have almost the same operator using the same way
if (mother?.children) {

}
else {
 // it is null, undefined, etc...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!variable && typeof variable === "object") {
    // variable is null
}
```

Comment: null is only thing that is "falsy" and typeof returns "object".

Comment: How is that better than `if (variable === null)`? Also someone already provided that answer last year: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27550756/218196 .

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in case of Boolean values coming from DB
for ex:

```
 value = false

 if(!value) {
   // it will change all false values to not available
   return "not available"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking error conditions:

```
// Typical API response data
let data = {
  status: true,
  user: [],
  total: 0,
  activity: {sports: 1}
}

// A flag that checks whether all conditions were met or not
var passed = true;

// Boolean check
if (data['status'] === undefined || data['status'] == false){
  console.log("Undefined / no `status` data");
  passed = false;
}

// Array/dict check
if (data['user'] === undefined || !data['user'].length){
  console.log("Undefined / no `user` data");
  passed = false;
}

// Checking a key in a dictionary
if (data['activity'] === undefined || data['activity']['time'] === undefined){
   console.log("Undefined / no `time` data");
   passed = false;
}

// Other values check
if (data['total'] === undefined || !data['total']){
  console.log("Undefined / no `total` data");
  passed = false;
}

// Passed all tests?
if (passed){
  console.log("Passed all tests");
}
```