# how to check for null value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating and registration form in java script want i want is to check that any of the fields should not be null 
the code is here

```
    enter code herefunction Savedata()
{
    var nameval= new String();
    var name1=document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
    var designaton=document.getElementById("designation").value;
    var passwrd=document.getElementById("password").value;
    var confrmpasswrd=document.getElementById("cnfrmpassword").value;
    var DOB=document.getElementById("date").value;
    var atdrate=email.indexof("@");
    var dot=email.lastindexof(".");
     if(nameval != null)
        {
            alert("Enter only Characters");
        }else if(atdrate!=email || dot!=email)
        {
            alert("Enter valid Email ");
        }
        else if(designaton!=nameval){
            alert("Enter only charaters in designation");
        }else if(password!=confrmpassword){
            alert("Password and conformPassword doesnt match");
        }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to check for null value in javascript-- google search returns so many result for this my friend

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check null values in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-to-check-null-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to compare the length insted comparing the value of the string in javascript...

For example, instead of comparing...

```
if(nameval == null)
{
  // your logic
}
```

you can verify...

```
if(nameval.length == 0)
{
 // your logic
}
```

Comment: want i want is i'm storing the value in name1 and its should not be null or empty

Comment: the name1.length will  be zero... when name1 is either null or empty... you can compare the condition by comparing name1.length to zero...it works...

Comment: thanks can anyone tell how to specify that fields contains only string without using regExp in javascript.

Comment: usage of regex is good... however, if you want to compare without regex.. the following should work.. funtiona isAlpha(str){for(var i=0;i<sr.length;i++){var ch = str.charAt(i); if(ch <= 'a' && ch >= 'z') return true; else return false;}}

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check the values like this:

```
if (!myValue) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

checks if nothing is entered in the input box

```
if(nameval == "")
    {
    //code
    }
```