# HTML -How to do error checking for null value input of textarea in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do some error checking in the script for the input of a textarea, i.e. if there is no input, showing an alert. I've tried to use value="" value='' , but seems all cannot work.

Field

```
 <div class="field">
        <label>remarks:</label>
        <textarea id="id_remarks" name="remarks"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Save button

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="verify()"/>
```

Function

```
<script>    
    function verify(){
    if (document.forms[0].elements['id_remarks'].value=='') {
        alert('Please enter the remarks')
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help on how to do it? thanks very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-to-check-null-values-in-javascript

Comment: The value of a form control is always a string, it is never `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Use a JS debugger. What's the actual value of `document.forms[0].elements['id_remarks'].value`? Set a breakpoint in `verify()` - does the function get called?

Comment: Anyway, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong in the code you've shown us (http://codepen.io/millimoose/pen/Avxwl), so I'm guessing your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it

```
function verify(){
    if(!document.getElementById('id_remarks').value.trim().length){
        alert("Please enter the remarks");
    }
 }
```

**Updated: Fixed for IE version < 9**

In IE below version 9, it is not support .trim()

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function'){
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `.trim()` will fail in IE8 and below

Answer (score 3):

```
var x=document.forms[0].elements['id_remarks'].value;

if(!x){} else {}
```

This checks for `("")`, `null`, `undefined`, `false` and the numbers `0` and `NaN`

Source :

[How do I check for null values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-to-check-null-values-in-javascript)

Comment: But the OP only needs to check for "", the value of a form control will never be anything other than a string.

Answer (score 1):

Validation is more commonly applied to a form's submit handler since a form can be submitted without clicking the submit button.

Comparing the value of the control with "" (empty string) should work, however the value might be whitespace so you might want to remove that first, e.g.

```
<form onsubmit= "return verify(this);" ...>
  <textarea id="id_remarks" name="remarks"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function verify(form) {
  if (form.remarks.value.replace(/\s+/g,'') == '') {
    alert('Please enter some remarks');
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you know you're in an ES5 environment. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkAEj/)

```
if (!document.getElementById('id_remarks').value.trim()) {
        alert('Please enter the remarks');
    }
```

`trim()` validates blank spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the `.value` of the `textarea` object to an empty string works fine (see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/mT3Y7/)).

The only think I can see that's odd about your code is the use of the `.elements` property of the form object.  I can't say that's it's wrong, just that it's not the way I'm used to seeing it done.  I'm used to identifying DOM objects using `document.getElementById()`.

In any case, the following works...

HTML:

```
<form id="f1" action="" method="post">
    <label for="ta1">TextArea</label>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="ta1"></textarea>
    <label for="result">Result:</label>
    <input id="result" type="text"></input>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="verify"></input>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ta1 = document.getElementById("ta1");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
f1.onsubmit = function () {
    if (ta1.value === "") {
        result.style.color = "red";
        result.value = "Blank";
    } else {
        result.style.color = "blue";
        result.value = "Not Blank: '" + ta1.value + "'";
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for the **length property**

```
if (!document.forms[0].elements['id_remarks'].value.length) {
```

Comment: A zero length string is equal to an empty string, i.e. if *a* is a string and `a.length == 0` then `a === ''`.

Comment: you should check not of document.forms[0].elements['id_remarks'].value.length

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle working http://jsfiddle.net/Q4JPs/8/

HTML

```
<div class="field">
        <label>remarks:</label>
        <textarea id="id_remarks" name="remarks"></textarea>
 </div>
<button id='btn'>Click me</button>
```

js

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function (){
    if (document.getElementById('id_remarks').value =="")
    {
        alert("is Empty");
        return;
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `required` attribute in HTML5, it works on all modern browsers, even if users have javascript disabled. Example:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="username" value="" title="username" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```