# Jquery code check array is null or not

Tags: jquery

In the bellow code

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "/signIn",
     dataType: "json",
     data: data,
     success: function (response) {
         alert("response----------------"+response) //[]
         if(response.length==0){
             alert("No data found")
         }
     }
  });
```

response is getting as `[]` and it doesn’t enter the if statement .

is there any possible way to check the empty array.

Comment: what is the problem with `if(response.length==0)` ?

Comment: what do you get if you try alert typeof(response); ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-to-check-null-values-in-javascript

Comment: It's not possible for `response` to be null; it has to be an array or an object - anything else would be invalid JSON and the `success` callback wouldn't execute.

Comment: There in nothing wrong in `if(response.length==0)` check your console for any errors.

Comment: alert typeof(response);  getting string

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/signIn",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data,
      success: function (response) {
        alert("response----------------"+response) //[]
        //modify if(response.length==0){
        if(!response || response.length==0){
            alert("No data found")
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that *the value returned by your API is not an array, maybe an object or string*.

check this using

```
console.log(typeof response);
```

Since you already use **`jQuery`** I would prefer to use **[`jQuery.isEmptyObject()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/)**

Try like this

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject(response);
```

From your comments, Since you mentioned string, then no way other way than this

```
if (response === "[]") //Better
if (response.length === 2) //Not good, yet can be used
```