# How do you assign a default value for a set Date format from API?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

Given the following data formats for ReleaseDate:

1. 2014-09-23 09:00:00.923Z
2. /Date(1407369600210)/

You can get the above information from an API with the following object dot-notation:

```
result.data.Items[0].ReleaseDate
```

However, there are cases where this particular data is *undefined* but how do you check if it **is** undefined and assign a default value/var?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

`if(!result.data.Items[0].ReleaseDate){
 result.data.Items[0].ReleaseDate = defaultValue;
}`

Which will check for empty strings `("")`, `null`, `undefined`, `false` and the numbers `0` and `Na`

Check:
[How do I check for null values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Ok i'll try a variation of this and get back to you.

Comment: Just tried it - I did a variation of this but this is the right idea for sure. thanks!