# Get last created sheet or sheet linked to form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Form that is run on a script. Every Monday there is a trigger that happens at a specific time and what it does is it opens the sign ups and sets the destination to a new sheet in a linked spreadsheet.

I am now writing another script that will get the results from those sign ups and do something with that data. The thing is, I can't seem to figure out how to get the specific spreadsheet where the form is throwing data into.

Now if I do something like this:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId());
Logger.log(ss.getSheetName());
```

The output will be the name of the first sheet in that spreadsheet. While this may work for me 90% of the time, I do run a risk of somebody going and messing with the order of the sheets. For this reason, I need to retrieve the exact sheet where the form is sending data into. How can I do this?

Comment: From what I gather, you could store last used spreadsheet id in `User Properties` and pick it from there next time.

Comment: @ParagJadhav I have the spreadsheet, I need the exact sheet though.

Comment: Then it is possible to store the sheet's  `id or name` in `User Properties`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Spreadsheet from a Google Forms submit trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058876/how-to-access-spreadsheet-from-a-google-forms-submit-trigger-function)

Comment: You could name the new sheets with a date with insertSheet(SheetName).  Then get all of the sheets with getSheets() and put of their names into an array.  Sort the array and take the array.length-1 element and that it's.  You can eliminate messing with the old sheets for now by filtering out the ones that don't have a date with something like regular expressions.