# how to check null in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

```
var someValue1 = '${requestScope.someValue}';
    var someValue = '${requestScope.someValue}';
    var someValue = '${requestScope.someValue}';
    if(someValue1 !== null && someValue1 !== undefined && someValue1 !== '' && someValue1!=='null'){
        alert('Your New someValue1 = '+someValue1);
    };
    if(someValue !== null && someValue !== undefined && someValue !== '' && someValue!=='null' ){
        alert('Error : ' + someValue +"\nDescription : " + someValue);
    };
```

i want to execute only one alert box depending on the values but null checking is not working.

My both alert boxes are getting executed and that is my main problem. i cant understand why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check for null values in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you have something processing those `'{$requestScope.someValue}'` string literals in some way? Because in your code above, you have the actual string `'{$requestScope.someValue}'`.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: No, that matches the title of this question, but not the content.

Comment: no i dont have anything processing it.

Comment: @tushargarg: Then that's your problem, it's exactly like `var someValue = 'foo';`. The value you're checking is the actual string `'{$requestScope.someValue}`.

Answer (score 4):

All of your values are **strings**, because you've put them in quotes:

```
var someValue1 = '${requestScope.someValue}';
// --------------^-------------------------^
```

Consequently, they'll never be `=== null` or `=== undefined`. Moreover, unless you have something processing those that you haven't shown, they'll never be `=== ''`, either, because they're the **literal string** `{$requestScope.someValue}` (exactly like `'foo'` is the literal string `foo`).

If you want to check the value, check the value itself, `requestScope.someValue`.