# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

Hello im having trouble of fixing this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null`. This is what i want to do, if i click to the day without event the `#myModal` will show but if i click the day with event the `#delete` modal will show. But my problem is when im clicking the day without event im getting an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null`.

[image]
here's the ajax

```
  dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    var datee = date.format();
                 $.ajax({
                url:'getrecords.php',
                method:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',     
                data:{
                  "filter": 1,
                  "start": datee

                },
                success:function(data){
                var date = data[2];    

                if(date == datee){
                  $('#delete').modal('show');
                }
                else{
                  $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }

                }
              });
```

here's the php

```
  if(isset($_POST['filter']))
   {
        $start = $_POST['start'];
         $select = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE start = '$start'");     
        $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($select);
      $array = mysqli_fetch_row($select);  
      echo json_encode($array);   
   }
```

Comment: based on the code you posted, it seems data in `success:function(data){` is null

Comment: So... It looks like `null` is the response (i.e. `data`) you get when there is no event. Test for that.

Comment: yeah it's null but when i click to the day with event it's not. how can i solve this sir? if the success function is null i want the #myModal to appear

Comment: `if(data === null){$('#myModal').modal('show');}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check for null values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript)

Comment: fix your php output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely the result of the data being passed into your success callback being null. Accessing it like it is an array will then yield the type error you are seeing. Without know too much about your app, maybe try changing your logic to:

```
//your previous code then handle success like:           

        success:function(data){
            if (data === null) {
               $('#myModal').modal('show');
            } else {
               $('#delete').modal('show');
            }            
         }
```

Comment: Edit: modified the case statement to reflect what I believe you are going for