# Ajax check value of data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm getting data as JSON response and each time one of my fields is empty and one has value so I need to make `if` statement to check which one has value and print that one.

So far I tried:

```
if(data.longtext_dec != ''){
  var ress = data.longtext_dec;
} else {
  var ress = data.text_dec;
}
```

and

```
if($.trim(data.longtext_dec) === '')
{
  var ress = data.longtext_dec;
} else {
  var ress = data.text_dec;
}
```

each time the code keeps printing `longtext_dec` or show both as `null`.

So I need help to get this right, the result of this `ress` I want to append it in my view (either this or that).

How can I fix this code?

## UPDATE

network response tab:

```
product_id        15
specification_id  5
text_dec          ddd
longtext_dec      null
id                69
```

payload

```
{"product_id":"15","specification_id":"5","text_dec":"ddd","longtext_dec":null,"id":69}
```

Comment: Can please you show an example of the json data in your post?

Comment: @Karl updated...

Comment: Try `var ress = data.longtext_dec || data.text_dec;`. In this case if `longtext_dec` is `null`, `undefined` or empty string, the `text_dec` will be used.

Comment: have you ever tryed 
if(!data.longtext_dec){
  var ress = data.text_dec;
 }else{
  var ress = data.longtext_dec;
 }

Comment: Which will check for empty strings (""), null, undefined, false and the numbers 0 and NaN

Comment: @ischenkodv it does work :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `if (data.longtext_desc)` it's a way to check if data variable evaluates to `true`. `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0`, an empty string evaluates to `false`.

```
    var ress; // undefined
    if (data.longtext_desc) {
      ress = data.longtext_desc;
    } else {
      ress = data.text_dec;
    }
```

Optionally use a ternary operator:

```
    var ress = data.longtext_desc ? data.longtext_desc : data.text_dec;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between empty string, null, undefined and boolean true/false. As shown in the JSON you want to check if the value from the response object is null. So just check

```
if( data.longtext_dec !== null )
```

Here is very well explained:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27550756/3868104

Optional you can check for whatever you want for example:

```
if( data.longtext_dec !== "" )
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can leverage javascript || operator as below

```
var res = data.longtext_dec || data.text_dec;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var data = {"product_id":"15","specification_id":"5","text_dec":"ddd","longtext_dec":null,"id":69};

var ress;

(data.longtext_dec !== null) ? ress = data.longtext_dec : ress = data.text_dec;

console.log(ress);
```