# Which way should be used for null comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

To check whether an object is null or not in javascript, i have seen two ways,

```
let obj = {};
```

**Option 1**

```
if(obj){ console.log('object exists'); }
```

**Option 2**

```
if(!!obj === true){ console.log('object exists'); }
```

Is there any advantage of choosing one option over the  other? which option is preferred as the standard code ?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript

Comment: You are not checking null. You are checking if obj has a truthy value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check for null values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @31piy `typeof null === "object"`, so you might not want to use it, unless you are checking if `obj` is either undeclared or actually `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use simple **===**.

In your code, you are not checking if the object is `null` or not. Instead, your code just checks if it's not a Falsy value. Note that there are a total of 6 Falsy Values in JavaScript, `null` being one of those. Read more about them [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/). If you just want to check if a variable is `null`, the following is the best way to go:

```
if (obj === null) { 
  console.log("object is null");
} else {
  console.log("object is not null");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to check if the object is null:

```
if(obj === null) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object in javascript is always truthy irrespective of whether it has any property defined on it.

Thus,

```
var obj={}
if(obj){
//this block will always be executed.
}
```

If you want to check if an object has been **defined in the current lexical scope** try:

```
if(typeof(obj) !== 'undefined' && obj !== null){ 
  console.log('object exists'); 
}
else{
  console.log('nope')
}
```

If you want to check if an object **has any property on it or it is an empty object** try:

```
if(typeof(obj) !== 'undefined' && obj !== null){ 
  console.log('object exists'); 
}
else{
  if(Object.keys(obj).length){
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: `typeof` always returns a `String` so `typeof(obj) === undefined` will **always** return `false`.

Comment: `typeof null` will return `"object"`, so `null` will pass your test, too.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)` will throw an error if `obj` is `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

To test if a value `obj` is of Object data type, try

```
if( obj and typeof obj === "object") {
     // obj is an object and it's safe to access properties
}
```

The truthiness of `obj` indicates it's not `null`, and `typeof` returning "object" means it's not some other primitive data type.

Note that `null` is its own data type in JavaScript (null), but `typeof null` returns "object" because of limitations in the early implementations of the language.

Conversely, to test if a value is `null` and not an object, simply use a strict equality test:

```
if( obj === null) {
   // the data type of obj is null
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Choosing a comparison method varies on how you predict how the data type will be,
but if you want a really safe standard, use 'typeof'.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

if( typeof obj === "object" ){ console.log('object exists'); }

if( typeof obj !== "undefined" ){ console.log('object exists'); }

Comment: But...that fails precisely for when an object is `null`! Because `typeof null === 'object'`