# How to save check to nullable object in react

Tags: reactjs

I would like to check the nullable object to toUpperCase.

Here is example=>

```
this.state.holidays.filter(e=>e.holidd.toUpperCase().includes(this.state.searchvalue.toUpperCase()) ||
                           e.holidesc.toUpperCase().includes(this.state.searchvalue.toUpperCase()));
```

This `holidesc` is can be null and null value can't check toUpperCase.So How can I save check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for null value first;

```
this.state.holidays.filter(
    e=>e.holidd.toUpperCase().includes(this.state.searchvalue.toUpperCase()) 
    ||
    (e.holidesc && e.holidesc.toUpperCase().includes(this.state.searchvalue.toUpperCase())));
```

[How do I check for null values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript/6003958)