# In JavaScript, is using `a == null` in fact the same as `a === null || a === undefined`?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

It took me a while to note to always use `===` in JavaScript instead of `==`.

But today I noticed

```
if (a == null) { ... }
```

seems identical as

```
if (a === null || a === undefined) { ... }
```

[from a table in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using).

I hope to know:

1. are they really identical?
2. is it recommended to use the form `a == null` instead of `a === null || a === undefined`?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27550756/3783478

Comment: Check this table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23465314/3082296

Comment: They are identical.

Comment: @Teemu only `null` and `undefined` pass the `a == null` condition

Comment: @Teemu guys, before shallow judgment is added for this question, DO NOTICE that `a == null` really is identical to `a === null || a === undefined`. Even the TC39 committee is using it

Comment: @nonopolarity In your answer you're talking about `?.` operator, but in your question there's nothing about it ..?

Comment: @Teemu Only `null == undefined` and vice versa is true https://stackoverflow.com/a/23465314/3082296. For example `0 == null` is false

Comment: @Teemu this is not instant noodles. Read the answer. The `?.` is only about how the TC39 checks whether something is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Amazing how things like this appear,.  It's certainly a nice trick `a == null`.   Would I personally use it.  That's a tricky one!!,. It seems fine once you know, but like @nonopolarity mentions it's so very easy for others to miss-read, especially as most linting will complain.  So, easy for another programmer to go, oh.  look he forgot an extra `=`.. :)

Comment: @Keith I know, you can state something advanced, and in 3 seconds, 10 intermediate negative opinion comes in

Comment: @nonopolarity  Yeah,:)  Well you got an upvote from me anyway.  Your answer was well written, and I'm totally baffled by the down-votes.. :(

Comment: @Keith I found that sometimes, when a question or answer is not useful for users to get points, it is immediately downvoted, because, it is no immediate gratifications

Comment: @Keith "*specially as most linting will complain*" you can configure your linter to allow `x == null` checks but not any other double equals. And if somebody is examining your code *without* using your lint settings, then they should stop. Alternative, if you're supplying code and not conforming to their lint settings, you should stop. So, all in all - linters shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: @VLAZ  but is this just ESLint,.. tried looking in JSLint & JSHint & standardJs, can't seem to find the option to just accept `== null`   Of course ESLint is the one I use, but I did say most linters, not all.

Comment: @Keith JSLint is a bad stick to compare against as it's *really* opinionated. It alone spawned the ecosystem of other linters that allow for more options.As for JSHint, it has had the [eqnull](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#eqnull) rule since before even ESLint existed.

Comment: @VLAZ  `JSLint is a bad stick to compare`,.. Yeah!!,.  Well it's good to know if I did want to start using this, Linting has me covered.  Make's me think again.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are identical, except for one case of `document.all` (please see the first comment). We can see that in the `==` chart, `null` and `undefined` compares to `true` only with itself and each other: `null == null` is `true`, and `null == undefined` is `true`, etc, and nothing else. So when we use `something == null`, the only `something` that can give a `true` is `null` and `undefined`:

[image]

Even the TC39 is using it that way:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/blob/master/README.md

> ```
> a?.b                          // undefined if `a` is null/undefined, `a.b` otherwise.
> a == null ? undefined : a.b
> ```

However, I don't recommend using it in common daily coding. That's because, if the code `a == null` is read by other programmers, they may immediately change it to `a === null` and if the test cases are not able to catch it, then a subtle bug might be introduced in the system.

In an open source project where you have the ultimate decision for what goes in and what doesn't, then it can be used, with your code review and approval. Or, if you use it once or twice and then with proper comment up above to state what you are trying to do.

Otherwise, most other programmers may think if you really aim to compare just to `null` and not considering for `undefined`. If you write `a === null || a === undefined`, then most everybody knows exactly what you are trying to do.

A third side effect is, if you say `a == null` is identical to `a === null || a === undefined`, you could attract tons of users on Stack Overflow, downvoting on you, saying don't ever use `==` in JavaScript.

An interesting fact is, even Babel translate `a?.b` to compare with both `null` and `undefined` (`void 0`), instead of just using `== null`. Babel doesn't really have to, but maybe it does that so that when a programmer reads the compiled code, it is more clear.

But I don't know how many interviewers have asked me if the line `if (a == null)` is good, and when I said we should use `===`, then I was viewed as just one step above greenhorn, because all the "pros" know that `a == null` is for checking whether `a` is `null` or `undefined`. So while maybe it is not good to actually use it in the code, it is good for testing if somebody is a pro.

Comment: I'm the TC39 Champion for optional chaining: We use `== null` in explainer docs because it's easier to understand. They are **not** equivalent though. `== null` is the same as `=== null || === undefined || === document.all` (in browsers, node does not have a `document.all`).

Comment: @Justin So in all cases, they are the same except the case of `document.all`?  `document.all` is like the "super" exception in JS as it is an object but `!!document.all` is false... so it is like something that can violate the law of physics