# Variable returning 'null' instead of null

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a very basic javascript function where I am splitting the string into two parts. The problem is the second part is 'null' and not null. So if function is not working properly

Please find below code and console.logs.

Why such strange behavior. Thank you in advance

```
  extractCredentials(request: Request): any {

    const authHeaderValue = request.headers.authorization;

    const parts = authHeaderValue.split(' ');
    const encryptedCredentails = parts[1];

    console.log(typeof encryptedCredentails) // prints string
    console.log(encryptedCredentails) // null
    console.log(encryptedCredentails.length) // prints 4

    if (encryptedCredentails == 'null') {
      console.log('null') // prints null
    }
    else {
      console.log('not null') // not executed
    }
    if (encryptedCredentails) {
      console.log('true') // true
    }
    else {
      console.log('false') // not executed
    }
    return encryptedCredentails
  }
```

Comment: are you looking to compare & validate to 'null' value ?? then it should be encryptedCredentails == null

Comment: the authHeaderValue is a string. you are implying a string can be null.

Comment: No, actually I want to check where the value is null or not

Comment: `'null'` != `null`

Comment: I guess your authorization header contains something like `Bearer null`

Comment: A string can't be null. It's a string.

Comment: you are doing a `.split(' ')` there.. if authHeaderValue was null, it would throw an exception

Comment: if the split gives you `'null'` (the string variant, and not the object one), then it is because there is a literal *null* in your authorization header. Please use dev console to check it and check the originating code where the auth headers are being set.

Comment: This is happening when auth headers are not getting set. When set no problem.

Comment: [`authHeaderValue.split(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) always produces an [array of strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Return_value). If `parts[1]` is the string `'null'` (it cannot be the `null` value) then this means that the second word of `authHeaderSplit` is "null".

Comment: What is the value of `authHeaderValue` when the problem happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse it like this JSON.parse(encryptedCredentails ) it return you null without ''

```
var encryptedCredentails  = 'null'
console.log(JSON.parse(encryptedCredentails )) //null
 console.log(encryptedCredentails ) //"null"
```

Comment: Why `JSON.parse()`? There is no JSON in this question.

Comment: "null" is a valid JSON. that's why I use  JSON.parese to pass the "null". Recently I use one API that returns "null" In response so when I parse it returns null without ".same situations here.

Answer (score 0):

This condition is checking for a string value of 'null', not the primitive type `null`.

```
    if (encryptedCredentails == 'null') {
      console.log('null') // prints null
    }
```

If you are trying to do a null check on `encryptedCredentails` then your condition should be one of the following possible options:

If you are **only trying to check for null values, and not other null-ish values**, then do a 'strict' equality check:

`if (encryptedCredentails === null)`

If you want to treat `undefined` `0` etc etc as `null, then use:

`if (encryptedCredentails == null)`

or

`if (!encryptedCredentails)`

see similar question on checking for null values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript)

Comment: i suggest using `===` instead. else it would also fail on 0, undefined, [], [[]], [,] and so on.

Comment: @amyoula this is the problem if (encryptedCredentails == 'null') is getting executed and not if (encryptedCredentails == null)

Comment: yes you are correct, I will update to clarify the difference. @GottZ

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting on the basis of whitespace " ", so it cannot be "not null" because it will split it also