# Error code "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am using a `for(){}` statement to loop through every element I have in order to change the text color and remove underlining when a function is called. After doing so, the function will then set the font color and underline the selected text. However, I keep receiving the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. I triple-checked My element's names, making sure that they were right. They were.

```js
let videos = ["video 1","video 2"];
let current_video = undefined;
window.onload = function () {
    function update_video(video) {
        // loops through all of my h2 elements to change their style to default
        for(var i = -1 ; i < videos.length ; i++) {
            document.getElementById(String("vid-"+i)).style.color = "#ca6735";
            document.getElementById(String("vid-"+i)).style.textDecoration = "none";
        }
        // sets the selected h2 element (using a button to select it) to a new color with an underline.
        current_video = Number(video);
        document.getElementById(String("vid-"+video)).style.color = "#49a1b6";
        document.getElementById(String("vid-"+video)).style.textDecoration = "underline";
    }
    document.getElementById("vid-bt-0").addEventListener("click", function() {
        update_video(0);
    });
    document.getElementById("vid-bt-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
        update_video(1);
    });
}
```

The code above is what I have currently. The code underneath the second comment works.

Comment: It's always good practice to check null before the use of properties. check null. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript

Comment: Check my answer. Happy coding @phantam :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess because of `i = -1` in `for` loop the problem occurs:

So, try with the below code:

```
        for(var i = 0; i < videos.length ; i++) {
            document.getElementById(String("vid-"+i)).style.color = "#ca6735";
            document.getElementById(String("vid-"+i)).style.textDecoration = "none";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice here is that your for loop starts at -1; so the first video is should be `vid--1`. Is that correct? If not, just make your loop start from 0 and not from -1.

If that's not the issue, try to `console.log` your strings such that you understand which is the problematic one.

Comment: Thank you, I will try these suggestions!

Comment: This worked. I changed the ```i=-1``` to ```i=0```.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is happening because you start the loop from i = -1?

Also, no need to use :

```
String("vid-"+i)
```

this will do the same:

```
"vid-" + i;
```