# Determine execution flow with nullchecks to operate components as best as possible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Many times I find myself in the need of checking which type of componenent am I handling to make the corresponding operations.

For example:

```
bool isFooAType = someGameObject.GetComponent<FooA>() != null;
bool isFooBType = someGameObject.GetComponent<FooB>() != null;

if (isFooAType) {
    FooA myFooA = someGameObject.GetComponent<FooA>();
    //FooA Operations....

}
if (isFooBType) {
    FooA myFooB = someGameObject.GetComponent<FooB>();
    //FooB Operations....

}
```

Is there a more condensed or more elegant way to determine the flow of execution depending on the component type to handle the corresponding operations and even maybe avoid doing `GetComponent` twice (one to check if its null + get again to operate the component in the code successively)?

Comment: What are the operations? Could you perhaps use an interface?

Comment: You could use [`TryGetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.TryGetComponent.html)

Comment: oh my god, that was kind of what I was looking for, thanks a lot

Comment: the question in inspired in how nullchecks can be done in [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003884/how-do-i-check-for-null-values-in-javascript)

Comment: You called the function twice, once to get the `isFooAType` and a second one inside the `if (isFooAType)`. That was a problem. You should either use the function Ackdari commented or something like: `FooA compA = someGameObject.GetComponent<FooA>();` and then `bool isFooAType = (compA != null);`

Comment: thanks @Cleptus, yes I was aware of that option. Like that you can avoid the double `GetComponent` but still need to check twice. `TryGetComponent` is what I was after, as both check can be done at once, moreover you avoid memory allocation in the editor, as explained [here](https://www.jiadongchen.com/2020/05/using-trygetcomponent-instead-of-getcomponent-to-avoid-memory-allocation-in-the-editor/).

Comment: note that for `TryGetComponent` to be available, needs to be available in the updated API in the Unity 2019.2 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned there is [`TryGetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.TryGetComponent.html) so you do simply

```
if (someGameObject.TryGetComponent<FooA>(out var fooA)) 
{
    fooA.DoSomething();
}
if (someGameObject.TryGetComponent<FooB>(out var fooB)) 
{
    fooB.DoSomehtingElse();
}
```

---

If this is not available (and only then) e.g. due to older Unity versions rather still make the call **ONCE** and do

```
var fooA = someGameObject.GetComponent<FooA>();
var fooB = someGameObject.GetComponent<FooB>();

if (fooA) 
{
    fooA.DoSomething();
}
if (fooB) 
{
    fooB.DoSomehtingElse();
}
```

---

In general you might want both to be exclusive by using `else if`.

And in particular if both are basically implementing the same method you would rather use a common base class or interface and have only one single `TryGetComponent` or `GetComponent` call.

Comment: I am wondering if the `if` avaluates regarding `null` or regarding the type's [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values). I will check that out. Thanks for any comments and for the answer.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay oh you can easily look this up in the source code for [`==`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L390) and [`implicit bool operator`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L98) ;) -> for comparing against actual `null` they cast to `System.Object` and use `== null` on that