# How to pass undefined into a function param

Tags: javascript

What is the proper way to send undefined as the value here in my test:

```
 it('returns response with no content status for no data found', function (done) {
        gateway.data('undefined');
        ...rest of code
        done();
    });
```

or should I do `gateway.data(undefined);`
or `gateway.data("undefined");`

purpose is I'm setting it to defined on purpose because my test needs to test that case in the calling function.

here's the gateway.data function:

```
module.exports = {
    data: function(someData){
        globalData = someData;
    },
    findAll: function(){
        return globalData;
    }
};
```

Comment: you can just omit it entirely.

Comment: If you don't pass a value, the parameters are set to `undefined` implicitly. However, if you are working with `arguments`, then there is a big difference between `foo(undefined)` and `foo()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass the value 'undefined' to a function with multiple parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998612/how-to-pass-the-value-undefined-to-a-function-with-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

You should go with `gateway.data(undefined);` as the others are passing a string and not `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to call `gateway.data();` someData will be undefined in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
 gateway.data(undefined);
```

as `undefined` is not a string but a variable

Comment: Actually, `undefined` is *variable*. It is not a [keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-keywords).

Comment: Thank you .. I now under stand that

Answer (score 0):

Pick one:

```
gateway.data(undefined);
gateway.data(void 0);
gateway.data();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gateway.data(); // implicitly: someData becomes undefined
```

About function [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Answer (score 0):

`gateway.data(undefined);` this way should work, what is the problem?

Also, the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) seems to be the most common way to explicitly get `undefined`.

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/HAr3M/42/)