# MongoDB comparison operators with null

Tags: spring, mongodb, null, spring-mongo

In MongoDB I would like to use $gt and $lt comparision operators where the value could be *null*.  When the operators did not work with *null*, I looked for documentation but found none.  In both cases it returned no documents (even though $ne, $gte, and $lte did return documents; meaning there were documents that were both equal to and not equal to *null*).

I would expect $gt to essentially operate like $ne (as the *null* type [Mongo comarison order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types-comparison-order) is so low) and $lt to return nothing for the same reason.

I was hoping this would work as the value I pass to the query is variable (potentially *null*), and I don't want to have to write a special case for *null*.

Example of what I was expeccting, given the following collection:

```
{
  id: 1,
  colNum: null
}
{
  id: 2,
  colNum: 72
}
{
  id: 3
}
```

I would expect the following query:

```
db.testtable.find( { "colNum" { $gt : null } } )
```

To return:

```
{
  id: 2,
  colNum: 72
}
```

However, nothing was returned.

Is there a reason that $gt and $lt don't seem to work with *null*, or is it a MongoDB bug, or is it actually supposed to work and there is likely a user error?

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Ha! @SalvadorDali good point.  Added final paragraph

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Nitty-Gritty Details

Reading through the [latest Mongo source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/7423c26ab95464a9b8f620ab4a11c297dc0621d5/src/mongo/db/matcher/expression_leaf.cpp#L105), there's basically 2 cases when doing comparisons involving `null`:

1. If the [canonical types](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/0f58d1037bcbfbf932e73e623772c4f815c361ad/src/mongo/bson/bsontypes.h#L124) of the BSON elements being compared are different, only equality comparisons (`==`, `>=`, `<=`) of null & undefined will return `true`; otherwise any comparison with `null` will return `false`. 
   **Note:** No other BSON type has the same canonical type as `null`.
2. If the [canonical types](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/0f58d1037bcbfbf932e73e623772c4f815c361ad/src/mongo/bson/bsontypes.h#L124) are the same (i.e., both elements are `null`), then [compareElementValues](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/0f58d1037bcbfbf932e73e623772c4f815c361ad/src/mongo/bson/bsonelement.cpp#L832) is called. For `null`, this just returns the difference between the [canonical type](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/0f58d1037bcbfbf932e73e623772c4f815c361ad/src/mongo/bson/bsontypes.h#L124) of both BSON elements and then carries out the requested comparison against `0`.
   For example, `null > null` would translate into `(5-5) > 0 --> False` because the canonical type of null is 5.
   Similarly, `null < null` would translate into `(5-5) < 0 --> False`.

This means `null` can only ever be equal to `null` or `undefined`. Any other comparison involving `null` will always return `false`.

### Is this a Bug?

*Updated Answer:*

The documentation for the comparison operators ([$gt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/), [$lt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/)) references [the documentation which you originally linked](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types-comparison-order), which implies that the comparison operators **should** work with `null`. Furthermore, query sorting (*i.e.*, `db.find().sort()`) **does** accurately follow the documented Comparison/Sort behavior.

This is, at the very least, inconsistent. I think it would be worth submitting a bug report to [MongoDB's JIRA site](https://jira.mongodb.org/).

---

*Original Answer:*

I don't think this behavior is a bug.

The [general consensus for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076944/800579) is that `undefined` means *unassigned* while `null` means *assigned but otherwise undefined*. Value comparisons against undefined, aside from equality, don't make sense, at least in a mathematical sense.

Given that BSON draws heavily from JavaScript, this applies to MongoDB too.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That was exactly what I was looking for. I'm not sure if I completely agree with the bug section though. I understand the historical relationship with JavaScript but they have since diverged a bit. Mongo has deprecated _Undefined_. Also in the Mongo documentation I reference the call it a _Comparison_ /Sort Order. Anybody have thoughts on this?

Comment: I had missed your link to the documentation. What the documentation says *does* accurately apply to sorting (_i.e._, `db.find().sort()`), but *not* to comparison operators in queries (_i.e._, `$gt`, `$lt`, _etc._). That certainly is confusing.

Comment: Note the `$lt` and `$gt` operators _in the aggregation pipeline_ act differently than `$lt` and `$gt` in normal query operators. In the aggregation pipeline `undefined` values are "less that" `null`. This is not true in standard queries. Thanks Mongo.