# Mongo projection to set value based on if a key exists or not

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo document that looks something like:

```
{
  bookings: [
    {complete: true, name: "John", checklist: {a: 1, b: 2}},
    {complete: false, name: "Kate"},
    {complete: true, name: "Mary", checklist: {a: 1, b: 2}}
  ]
}
```

I have a aggregation with a projection that looks like:

```
{
  $project: {
    'bookings.complete': 1,
    'bookings.name': 1
  }
}
```

Which returns the array of bookings, with only the complete and name keys.

I now want to add a key called `hasChecklist` that is `true` if the checklist exists, and `false` otherwise.

But I'm stuck because this projection will always return `true` for some reason :(

```
{
  $project: {
    'bookings.complete': 1,
    'bookings.name': 1
    'bookings.hasChecklist': { $ne: ['$bookings.checklist', null] }
  }
}
```

Basically I get

```
{
  bookings: [
    {complete: true, name: "John", hasChecklist: true},
    {complete: false, name: "Kate", hasChecklist: true},
    {complete: true, name: "Mary", hasChecklist: true}
  ]
}
```

When I want

```
{
  bookings: [
    {complete: true, name: "John", hasChecklist: true},
    {complete: false, name: "Kate", hasChecklist: false},
    {complete: true, name: "Mary", hasChecklist: true}
  ]
}
```

Anyone know what the correct expression in the projection should be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to project whether field exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720388/how-to-project-whether-field-exists)

Comment: Not exactly, because having arrays in this case makes the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `$project` below:

```
{
    "bookings": {
        "$map": {
            "input": "$bookings",
            "as": "booking",
            "in": {
                "complete": "$$booking.complete",
                "name": "$$booking.name",
                "hasChecklist": { "$gt": [ "$$booking.checklist", null ] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should return the following result:

```
{
    "bookings" : [
        {
            "complete" : true, 
            "name" : "John", 
            "hasChecklist" : true
        }, 
        {
            "complete" : false, 
            "name" : "Kate", 
            "hasChecklist" : false
        }, 
        {
            "complete" : true, 
            "name" : "Mary", 
            "hasChecklist" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Works!! <3 <3 <3