# Why destructuring assignment doesn't know null value as falsy and use default value?

Tags: javascript, destructuring, object-destructuring, falsy

Assume we have a function that use some keys in the inner object of argument:

```js
const api = ({ data: { name } = {} }) =>
  `My name is ${name}.`;
```

If we pass `{}`, `{ data: '' }`, `{ data: 0 }`, `{ data: NaN }` or `{ data: undefined }` to the function we will see:

```js
'My name is undefined.'
```

And won't see any error, because destructuring assignment sees the `data` is falsy and use  `= {}` instead then the `name` will be `undefined`.

**Question**: *Why destructuring assignment return error when we pass `null` to data key?*

```js
api({ data: null });

// ==> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of '{}' as it is null.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) concerning default values in object destructuring:

> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value
> pulled from the object is undefined.