# Destructuring an optionally chained object, to get the ...rest?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining, nullish-coalescing

I have this setup

```js
const { discard_me, ...rest } = some?.optional?.chaining;
```

I end up with an error that `discard_me` doesn't exist, but that's expected if `chaining` is also non-existent. It seems like the optional chaining should cover the concerns of both the left and right hand side of the assignment.

Is there a way round this without nullish coalescing?

Comment: What's wrong with adding `|| {}` or `?? {}`

Comment: Because that should/could be handled by the optional chaining?

Comment: It's not. These are two separate concerns; the RHS resolves to either `some.optional.chaining` or `undefined`, and the latter definitely can't be destructured (also the former *maybe* can't be).

Comment: That is what nullish coalescing is for.  [MDN even has an example combining both](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Combining_with_the_nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [destructuring falsey and null with default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522014/destructuring-falsey-and-null-with-default-parameters)

Comment: @jonrsharpe that would be an excellent answer

Comment: The answer is simply, `const { discard_me, ...rest } = some?.optional?.chaining || {}` as you cannot destructure `undefined`. This will not throw the error anymore.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I got this question opened so you'd have an opportunity to answer it with your comment. I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like the optional chaining should cover the concerns of both
> the left and right hand side of the assignment.

It doesn't, because `some?.optional?.chaining` is either going to resolve to:

- `some.optional.chaining` (which *may* be undefined); or
- `undefined` (which definitely is).

For the destructuring assignment, the right-hand side **must** be an object.