# react-native Destructuring props

Tags: react-native

Why do I get an undefined error or null error when I set a default value when destructuring props?
I saw on MDN that I can set default values ​​when doing destructuring.
When the value is null, it cannot be referenced, so I put the default value as an empty array, but I don't know why the error occurs. Shouldn't a default value be set when referencing a property to be null?
I would really appreciate it if you could let me know what I did wrong.

```js
//This is the props dummy data value.
displayOptions = {
 isVisible: true,
 displayImages : null,
 setting:{...some data}
 ....
}
```

```js
class DisplayScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {displayImages = []} = this.props.displayOptions ;  
     <React.Fragment>
            {!this.state.isShowMenu && displayImages.length > 0 && (
              <React.Fragment>
                <S3Image
                  imgKey={displayImages[0].key}
                  level={displayImages[0].level}
                />
                ....
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
           ......
     </React.Fragment>


  }
}
```

Comment: Try to verify that `this.props` actually contains `displayOptions`

Comment: Checked that t```his.prop```s has a ```displayOptions```
Do you have any other reason to guess?

Comment: What is the exact error you're seeing? Can you post the console output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522045/10657559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may due to **displayImages** haven't property length since its value is ***null***. Only ***undefined*** will take default value. Like below

```
displayOptions = {
 isVisible: true,
 displayImages : undefined,
 setting:{...some data}
 ....
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49233952/10657559)
from duplication issue [destructuring assignment default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233891/destructuring-assignment-default-value)