what does const {foo=20} = bar mean in javascript?
I couldn't find anything to search on for this. Based on my limited testing it looks like after
const {foo = 20} = bar

foo will have the value bar.foo if it exists otherwise it will have the value 20, i.e. it's equivalent to:
const foo = bar?.foo ?? 20

is my understanding correct?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Not the same outcome when bar is { foo: null }

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39522014/3001761

No it's not exactly equivalent.
Difference:
With ({foo = 20}), default value is used if bar.foo is undefined, but not if bar.foo is null.
const {foo = 20} = bar

With (??), the default value is used for null or undefined.
const foo = bar?.foo ?? 20



let bar = { foo: null };
const { foo = 20 } = bar;
console.log(foo); // null (not 20)

bar = { foo: null };
const fooVal = bar?.foo ?? 20;
console.log(fooVal); // 20



