# Javascript producing 'undefined' value

Tags: javascript

I'm populating the `src` attribute of an image dynamically with the following code:

```
function getLocalUrl(item) {
    if (item.item_id != null && item.item_id != "") {
        return host + "images/" + item.item_tid + "-" + item.item_id + ".jpg";
    } else {
        return host + "images/temp/" + item.item_tid + ".jpg";
    }
}
... 
var cont = "<img class=\"image image-large\" src=\"" + getLocalUrl(item) + "\"/>";
$(element).append(cont);
```

However when I look at the http requests that my browser makes I see two of them: the first one to

```
/images/undefined-1.jpg
```

and the second one to

```
/images/correctstring-1.jpg
```

Of course the first one produces an error but the second one downloads the images correctly so the end result is correct. But I still don't understand why the first request is made. The function getLocalUrl is only called once and the `item_tid` field is always defined (otherwise the second request wouldn't be produced). I'm a bit of a newbie so I might be missing something very basic.

Comment: Can we have an example of `item` please ?

Comment: You should also check `item.item_tid` because is that what's undefined.

Comment: Remember that in JS `null` and `undefined` is not the same. You can find more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: Considering the code you've posted appears to work exactly as expected for the correctstring example, and you say that `getLocalUrl` is called only once, have you considered looking elsewhere in the code for things that append `<img>` tags? I mean, based on the information given, there's no reason to suspect the code shown is faulty (even if it does fail to check the values). You could put a `console.log` line into the function if you want to check.

Comment: So, splinter, does either of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (item.item_id != null && item.item_id != "") {
```

With:

```
if (item.item_id != null && item.item_id != "" && item.item_tid) {
```

Or, shorter:

```
if (item.item_id && item.item_tid) {
```

You weren't checking for `item_tid` being `undefined`.

---

However, this will result in `return host + "images/temp/" + item.item_tid + ".jpg";` being used. Since `item_tid` is `undefined`, you're still not getting the result you want.

The problem is that, *if* `item_tid` is `undefined`, you can't build an url based on that.

Comment: `item_id` never gave any undefined at his code. It's the `item.item_tid` that returned undefined.

Comment: Right, fixed that. Completely overlooked the `t`.

Comment: well it turned out to be a completely different problem, my function was mistakenly being called by another library with a bad input. Anyway the answer does plainly solve the issue so I accepted it.

Comment: Much appreciated, @splinter123.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `item.item_tid` is undefined, since seeing from your code `item.item_tid` is undefined.

Change

```
if (item.item_id != null && item.item_id != "") {
```

with

```
if (item.item_id && item.item_tid) {
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment.