# How to sort stacked bars in d3?

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, stacked-chart

I'm trying to sort a horizontal stacked bar chart in d3, but keep coming up with undefined values which mess up my sorting. I was referencing [Cyril's code](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/pncze5gn/5/) but I keep getting "a.total = undefined". (It comes in the later half of the code, I've commented it out for you guys.)

Other than making sure this code sorts properly, my question is:

1. Why is it undefined? Am I referencing attributes of different datasets wrong?
2. If so, how does one access attributes of their respective datasets without being confined to being inside a function?

I am entirely new to d3 and javascript so any comments would be of great help and I appreciate any efforts to help! :)

```js
//the stacks
var headers = ["AR_Score_2015", "ER_Score_2015", "FS_Score_2015", "CF_Score_2015", "IF_Score_2015", "IS_Score_2015"];

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  },
  width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .2);

var z = d3.scale.category10();

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

//***Canvas setup***/
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var csv = "Uni,AR_Score_2015,ER_Score_2015,FS_Score_2015,CF_Score_2015,IF_Score_2015,IS_Score_2015\n\
A,400,400,400,400,400,382\n\
B,400,400,394.4,400,399.6,304\n\
C,400,400,400,374.8,384.8,386.4\n\
D,400,400,398,399.6,390.4,291.2\n\
E,399.2,358.4,400,400,360.8,340.8\n\
F,400,400,400,355.6,391.2,386.4\n\
G,399.6,399.2,394.4,352,382,399.6\n\
H,399.6,400,399.6,318.4,400,400\n\
I,399.6,396,314.4,395.2,400,392\n\
J,399.6,385.2,375.2,366,293.6,326.4\n\
K,400,394,371.6,400,188.8,272.8\n\
L,400,400,371.6,315.6,400,370\n\
M,381.2,390,376.8,346,400,376\n\
N,400,400,400,285.2,359.6,262\n\
O,388.8,296,400,339.6,386.4,284.8\n\
P,399.6,386.8,295.6,388.4,360.8,264\n\
Q,395.2,389.6,400,322,211.6,266.4\n\
R,380.8,383.6,359.6,310,381.6,392.8\n\
S,398.8,392,341.2,286,372.4,391.6\n\
T,400,397.6,400,268,132,359.2\n\
U,396.4,378.8,323.2,281.6,353.2,369.2\n\
V,398.4,398,350,336.8,191.2,144.4\n\
W,400,399.6,187.6,399.6,387.2,317.2\n\
X,400,398.8,296.8,358.4,229.6,196\n\
Y,377.2,367.2,263.2,357.6,400,388\n\
Z,385.6,338.4,399.2,341.6,60.8,229.6";
var csvBase64 = btoa(csv);
//***CSV START***/
d3.csv("data:text/plain;base64," + csvBase64, type, function(error, scores) {
  if (error) throw error;

  scores.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Overall_Score_2015 = +d.Overall_Score_2015;
    d.AR_Score_2015 = +d.AR_Score_2015;
    d.ER_Score_2015 = +d.ER_Score_2015;
    d.FS_Score_2015 = +d.FS_Score_2015;
    d.CF_Score_2015 = +d.CF_Score_2015;
    d.IF_Score_2015 = +d.IF_Score_2015;
    d.IS_Score_2015 = +d.IS_Score_2015;
  });


  //***Stacking***/

  var layers = d3.layout.stack()(headers.map(function(c) {
    return scores.map(function(d) {
      return {
        x: d.Uni,
        y: d[c]
      };
    });
  }));
  var count = 0;
  var i = 0;

  var layers2 = layers.map(function(scores) {

    return scores.map(function(d) {
      d.width = 0;
      var l = scores.length;
      if (count == l * 5 + i) {
        d.total = d.y0;
        i++;
      }
      count++;
      return {
        x: d.y,
        y: d.x,
        x0: d.y0,
        parent: d
      };
    });
  });


  //***Drawing***/

  y.domain(layers2[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  }));
  x.domain([0, d3.max(layers2[layers2.length - 1], function(d) {
      return d.x / 4 + d.x0 / 4;
    })])
    .nice();

  color.domain(d3.keys(scores[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== "Uni";
  }));

  var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers2)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(0," + 0 + ")";
    })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return z(i);
    })
    .attr("class", "stack");

  layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.x0 / 4);
    })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("width", function(d) {
      d.parent.width += x(d.x) - x(d.x0);
      return -(x(d.x0 / 4) - x(d.x / 4 + d.x0 / 4));
    })
    .on("click", function() {
      sortBars();
    });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(yAxis);


  //***Sorting***/

  function sortBars() {

    //***Problem here***//
    var z = y.domain(layers2.sort(function(a, b) {
          console.log("a.total = " + a.total, a, b);
          return b.total - a.total;
        })
        .map(function(d) {
          return d.layers2;
        }))
      .copy();

    //*** This is the code I was referencing from ***/
    var y0 = y.domain(layers2.sort(this.id == "test" ?
          function(a, b) {
            return b.total - a.total;
          } :
          function(a, b) {
            return d3.ascending(a.total, b.total);
          })
        .map(function(d) {
          return d.layers2;
        }))
      .copy();
    console.log(y0);

    svg.selectAll(".stack")
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        console.log("y0(a.total) = " + z(a.total));
        console.log("y0(b.total) = " + z(b.total));
        return z(a.total) - z(b.total);
      });

    var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
      delay = function(d, i) {
        return i * 50;
      };

    transition.selectAll(".stack")
      .delay(delay)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(0," + z(d.total) + ")";
      });

    transition.select(".y.axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .selectAll("g")
      .delay(delay);
  }
});

function type(d) {
  headers.forEach(function(c) {
    d[c] = +d[c];
  });
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mdn documentation about [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Undefined) says:

> A primitive value automatically assigned to variables that have just
>   been declared or to formal arguments for which there are no actual
>   arguments.

However if it doesn't help you much check [this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript).

You're getting `a.total = undefined` becuase of this expression:

```
if (count == l * 5 + i) {
  d.total = d.y0;
  i++;
}
```

Which only sets `total` property if the condition is `true`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the tip about undefined! I didn't know about that! However, I still face problems. My `z` continues to generate a static value of 75 which resulted in my bars transforming a uniform distance in the same direction, namely `z(a.total) = 75` and `z(b.total) = 75`. How does the declaration of `z` lead to this number?