# null and undefined in objects

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

this is my code :

```
<body>
     <p id="x"></p>
     <p id="y"></p>
    <form action="2.php" method="post" name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="srch">
    </form>
    <script>
        obj = document.forms["frm"]["srch7"];
        obj1 = document.getElementById("noexist");
        document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = obj;
        document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = obj1;
    </script>
</body>
```

why obj return undefined but obj1 return null, document.forms["frm"]["srch7"]; and  document.getElementById("noexist"); both are object and must return null,because elements no exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both cases are different,

```
obj = document.forms["frm"]["srch7"];
//Here you are trying to access a property that 
// is not present under document.forms.frm.

obj1 = document.getElementById("noexist");
//Here it is returning null because getElementById implemented in that way.
// getElementById will return null if the DOM search didn't find any element
// based on the supplied id.
```

Comment: why document.getElementsByName("noexist"); return nothing; this statement is like document.getElementsById("noexist")

Comment: @ehsan It will not return nothing. It will return an empty `nodeList`

Comment: why return null,like document.getElementsById("noexist") that return null ?

Answer (score 2):

Because form with the id `frm` exists, and its property `srch7` is undefined, means not defined. But in case when you are trying to get element by id `noexist` that element is null, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: *document.getElementById* is required to return *null* by the related specification: [*W3C DOM Level 4*](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid).

Answer (score 1):

Because, here you are trying to get the object/element from the dom and if it doesn't find the object/element it returns object's empty default value i.e. `null`

```
obj1 = document.getElementById("noexist");
```

And here you are trying to get the value of a field (not the object) and if it doesn't find any value assigned to that field or variable it retuns `undefined`.

`undefined` means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned a value

```
obj = document.forms["frm"]["srch7"];
```

See this post [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
 obj = document.forms["frm"]["srch7"];
 obj1 = document.getElementById("noexist");
```

- Here for `obj` `document.forms["frm"]` is `null` so the property of any `null` object is `undefined.`
- And for `obj1` the value of `document.getElementById("noexist");` is null.
- So these are the difference between these two objects.