# How do I avoid null values for mailApp in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send an automated email to a bunch of people in my office using Google Apps Script from a Google Sheet. We built it and it worked fine but now we have to add another recipient for each email as a CC. This isn't a huge problem either but I cant figure out how to ignore the null values (not all have a second person to CC). Here is my script, I might just be nesting the if statement incorrectly?

```
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var priorityValues = priority[i][0];
var autostatValues = autostat[i][0];
if(priorityValues == 'P0' && autostatValues != 'Launched') {
  // if it's P0, do something with the data.
  var emailFinal = email[i][0] + '@company.com';
  var ttFinal = tt[i][0] + '@company.com';
  var bugFinal = bugNumber[i][0];
  var sumFinal = sumtotal[i][0];
  var subject = 'Please update your info';
  var msg = 

  '<html><body>message is here
  </body></html>'
    ;


   if(tt[i][0] !== null) {  
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailFinal, subject, "", {htmlBody: msg, noReply:true, cc: ttFinal})}
  else {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailFinal, subject, "", {htmlBody: msg, noReply:true})}

        }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I missed that. I did forget to switch around the order too, just edited the original. The issue I am getting is that it still gives me there error for '@company.com' not being an email address, even though it should be ignored if tt is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing (unassigned) values are not null in JavaScript, they are undefined.  For an undefined value, `tt[i][0] !== null` returns true. See [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076944)

Solution: instead of `if (tt[i][0] !== null)`, use `if (!tt[i][0])`.

The code would also work with `if (tt[i][0] != null)` or `if (tt[i][0] !== undefined)`.

But `!==` is the negation of strict comparison `===`, which cares about the difference between undefined and null.

Comment: Thanks! Right when you posted this, I figured it out. Appreciate the quick response @meta