# When null should be used in javascript instead of undefined?

Tags: javascript

What are the use cases of null in java-script?When null Should be used instead of undefined?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

This is a **really** broad question. You can/should use `null` whenever you want something that looks like an object reference but has no value. `null` is the object-reference-type version of `undefined` (or `undefined`is the non-object-reference-type version of `null`).

There are a couple of places you *may* **have** to use `null` rather than `undefined` or something else: When dealing with host-provided objects that expect an object reference. Say we have a host-provided object `foo` that has a property `thingy` that may have a reference to another host-provided object. Because the host environment isn't required to make its objects full JavaScript objects, you may find that you get an error assigning a non-object-reference-type value like `undefined` to `foo.thingy` where assigning `null` to it works. (That said, most host environments will apply type coercion in that situation, and a large number of them now provide true JavaScript objects rather than fake ones.)