# Why does null == undefined evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript

I have a code below which is not clear to me

```
var a = null; 
if(a==undefined)
alert("true");
else 
alert("false");
```

When I ran above code it alerts true.

Can anybody explain whats the reason or concept behind this?

Comment: Try `===` instead of `==` ;-)

Comment: datatype of null is "object" whereas for undefined its "undefined" and I think there is no similarity for null and undefined then why its print true?

Comment: Note the details for the abstract equality operator (or rather just a copy of the specs petty much) is also defined in the [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/208/comparison-operations/796/abstract-equality#t=201607280802422140727).

Comment: Hi Alvaro yes I know === compares value as well as datatype but in my case I only check value between null and undefined how is it possible that null and undefined both having same value? Is there any concept or my confusion to understand this?

Comment: @VijayBarnwal: They don't have the *same* value, but their values are loosely equal according to the definition of loose equality in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Spencer I got your answer and really it solve the confusion.

Comment: Thanks T.J. but can you please elaborate loosely equal word in javascript?

Answer (score 15):

It's true because `==` is the **loose** equality operator, and `null` and `undefined` are loosely equal (`null == undefined` is true). If you use the strict equality operator, `===`, they are not equal (`null === undefined` is false).

Basically, the loose equality operator will coerce its operands if they're of different types (see [*Abtract Equality Comparison*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) in the spec). `0 == ""` is true, for instance, because if you coerce `""` to a number, it's `0`. The strict equality operator considers operands of different types not equal (see [*Strict Equality Comparison*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-strict-equality-comparison)); it does not coerce.

---

On browsers, there's a third value that's `==` to `null` and `undefined`: `document.all`. `document.all` behaves like `undefined` in various specification operations. This is so that really, really old code that was using `if (document.all)` or similar to go an IE-specific direction doesn't do that on modern browsers, since the features that they were avoiding exit on IE versions that handle `document.all` this way. This is [defined in the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-IsHTMLDDA-internal-slot).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The rules are also stated in [mozila developers network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Answer (score 0):

The [specifications](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) for the `==` operator is defined so that `null == undefined` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The spec - [Clause 11.9.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) . See clauses 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operators operate by converting operands into numbers before comparing. I understood this by an example, which is:
Consider you're writing a program to give access to employees into their account. You ask for credentials and the user input nothing.
Ideally, you keep asking until it's provided because null is equal only to undefined under ==, which a special case in comparison operation.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35613575)

Answer (score -1):

`undefined` means a variable has not been defined, or given a value. `null` is a special **object** within `javascript`.

Comparing the values using equals `==` will always give you `true` because they are both basically the same in value `(0, nothing, nada, zip)`.

Using strict equals `===` though, will return `false` because null is an `object` and `undefined` is just a blank `variable`.

Answer (score -1):

If a variable is pointing to nothing, it's null. That's similar in concept to an undefined variable, which has not yet been initialized.

Javascript interpreted this to make loose equality (==) treat null and undefined the same way. Strict equality (===) is more picky; if you have different data types such as null and undefined, they won't be equal.

See [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript) on differences between undefined and null and 
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

This behavior stems from JavaScript being a loosely-typed language. In the case of equality, this means values of differing data types can be compared.

Both `null` and `undefined` are considered "falsy", therefore they're loosely considered equal.

Logically, if `null == false` and `undefined == false`, then `null == undefined`.

Comment: *"Both null and undefined are considered "falsy", therefore they're loosely considered equal."* Nope, lots of falsy values aren't loosely equal to each other. `0 == null` is `false`, `false == undefined` is `false`, `NaN == ""` is `false`, ...