# Checking if a node exists in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if a node exists in an array but can't seem to get my if statement correct.

I've currently got :

```
if (obj2["spec"]["3"]["spec2"]["14"] != null) { do stuff }
```

In some cases [14] wont exist as the array length is only 5 or 6, so want to make sure it doesn't try to do anything if [14] doesn't have any items in it.

Comment: Syntax error: Missing `(` after `if`.

Comment: sorry that's my poor typing on here, i've got that in the code.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: check this with `undefined` like this `if (obj2["spec"]["3"]["spec2"]["14"] != undefined) { do stuff }` may be that can help you.

Answer (score -2):

You snippet is correct, when a node doesn't exist, is undefined, but in no-strict comparation, undefined == null.
If a node doesn't exist, will show a error. if you use typeof, this will cover if all nodes is valid.

Example

```
// ["spec2"] is undefined, this case will show a error.
if(array["spec"]["3"]["spec2"]["14"] != undefined) { 

}

// This doesn't he show error, if "specs2" is undefined.
if(typeof array["spec"]["3"]["spec2"]["14"] !== "undefined") { 

}
```

Comment: `typeof` can never return `undefined`. It may return the *string* `"undefined"`...

Comment: @lonesomeday Sorry, I forgot the quotation marks. I corrected

Comment: OP's `!= null` already ensures it's not undefined. What does your answer attempt to fix?

Answer (score -2):

If the array length is only 5 or 6, then it means element `14` won't even exist, you should be checking for undefined not null:

`if(typeof array["spec"]["3"]["spec2"]["14"] !== "undefined")`

or:

`if(array["spec"]["3"]["spec2"]["14"] !== undefined)`

or even:

`if(!array["spec"]["3"]["spec2"]["14"])`

I would recommend an option but it really comes down to preference and I'd rather not incite a style/best practice war :) Just pick whichever you prefer.

[Here's a thorough explanation on the difference between null and undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript), but essentially `null` means the value is `null`, whereas undefined means the variable has not been declared.

Comment: Or even `!= null`, which is what OP is doing. What does your answer attempt to fix?

Comment: `!= null` is wrong. If you try to access an element in an array which has not been defined yet, it will be undefined not null. try defining an empty array and checking if `arr['something'] == null`, you'll see it returns false

Comment: But `undefined == null`. It's an abstract comparison, not strict.