# ng-show not working angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have button that I want to disable when local storage is empty

```
<button ng-show="LS_wimmtkey!==null">{{LS_wimmtkey}}</button>
```

Button value shows null, but it is shown, why could that be? I tried writing `ng-show="1===2"` when it worked correctly, so the problem is with `LS_wimmtkey`

this is how I use it:

in `main.controller.js`:

```
$rootScope.LS_wimmtkey = localStorage.getItem('LS_wimmtkey');
    $rootScope.$watch("LS_wimmtkey", function() {
    localStorage.setItem('LS_wimmtkey', $rootScope.LS_wimmtkey);
```

My main.view is inserted into the review.view (because form and reviews are on the same page, main is for the review listing and reviews are submitted form)

I add values to local storage after submit in `review.controller.js`

```
function submit() {  
    if($rootScope.name!=null)    {
        var JSONObject = {
             "name":$rootScope.name,
             "surname":$rootScope.surname,
             "email":$rootScope.email,
             "review":$rootScope.review
            }
        var temp={
            "name":$rootScope.name,
             "surname":$rootScope.surname,
             "email":$rootScope.email
        }
        $scope.localArray.push(temp);
        $rootScope.LS_wimmtkey = $scope.localArray;
       // $rootScope.localStorageService.set("LS_wimmtkey", $scope.localArray);debugger;
       // $rootScope.LS_wimmtkey= localStorageService.get("LS_wimmtkey"); debugger;


        var Results = UniversalService.PostReview(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
        }
    }
```

I print `console.log($rootScope.LS_wimmtkey);` and it is null, so why button is not hidden?

Comment: once try using `ng-if` <button ng-if="LS_wimmtkey!==null">{{LS_wimmtkey}}</button>. let me know if it works.

Comment: are you sure it is null, and not undefined?

Comment: @Ved not working either :(

Comment: @mehulmpt I named my button with the same value and my button title is null, also I print that value in console which also shows it's null

Comment: Try with this if you have null as a string <button ng-show="LS_wimmtkey!=='null'">{{LS_wimmtkey}}</button>

Comment: @Dixit `<button ng-show="LS_wimmtkey!=='null'">{{LS_wimmtkey}}</button> ` that worked!!! Thank you so muuuch! Should have thought of that earlier!

Comment: @monikakalt that's technically incorrect. you're then assigning LS_wimmtkey a string value of null instead of actual null somewhere in your code. This might confuse any future developer seeing your code :)

Comment: @mehulmpt what would be correct way to do it then? :) I want to learn the right way

Comment: Look in your code where you're assigning LS_wimmtkey a value of "null" ("null" inside quotes.) get rid of the quotes and your current code would work. I'd also suggest you to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this **null**, I think your null as a string, that's technically incorrect but might help you.

```
<button ng-show="LS_wimmtkey!=='null'">{{LS_wimmtkey}}</button>
```

Comment: you can simply do it with `ng-show="LS_wimmtkey"` . You assigning  Ls_wimmtkey to null as string

Answer (score 2):

yes we cant be check null by `LS_wimmtkey!==null` probably its string   it always return true 
I'd suggest you:

`<button ng-show="LS_wimmtkey">{{LS_wimmtkey}}</button>`

try this it will work it will work with `undefine` `null` etc...

Answer (score 0):

"LS_wimmtkey" belong to $rootScope, 
please assign this variable to controller scope.
because $rootScope does't bing to template.

Fix is:

```
        $scope.LS_wimmtkey = localStorage.getItem('LS_wimmtkey');
        $rootScope.$watch("LS_wimmtkey", function() {
        localStorage.setItem('LS_wimmtkey', $scope.LS_wimmtkey);
```