# Why does isNil method in Lodash use null instead of undefined?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Why does `isNil` method in Lodash use `null` instead of `undefined`?

```
function isNil(value) {
  return value == null;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It makes no difference either way in terms of the logic using `null` or `undefined` as `null == undefined == true`, but using `null` instead of `undefined` would make the file size smaller by 5 bytes.

It's simply done to save a few bytes making the file smaller and *faster* to download from the server.

Comment: Also this may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 15):

To understand this a bit better, it's important to note that `lodash` is using `==` here instead of `===`.

Take the following example:

```
console.log(null == undefined);    // true
console.log(null === undefined);   // false
```

By using `==` (double equals), lodash is utilizing type coercion where `null` and `undefined` will be coerced to **falsy** values. As a result, `null == undefined` is `true`.

However, if using `===` (triple equals), no coercion is enforced, which means the types must be **identical**, and as we know `null` is not identical to `undefined`. As a result, `null === undefined` is `false`.

Comment: It looks like the main value of _.isNil is to avoid confusing someone like me who can never remember the subtleties of these coercion rules. If I see _.isNil when doing a code review it looks fine, but if I see == instead of === it raises a red flag.