# Get string value of template variable

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this in a template:

```
<div>{{String(element.elementId)}}</div>
```

but I get this error:

```
TableBasicExample.html:6 ERROR TypeError: _co.String is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (TableBasicExample.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14727)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13841)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14119)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13842)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
```

what I want to do is display the string literal "null" if `element.elementId` is null, or display "undefined" if `element.elementId` is `undefined`, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ternary out:

```
<div>{{ element.elementId ? String(element.elementId) : "undefined or null"}}</div>
```

Why do you need to know the if it's null vs undefined? It slightly complicates the check but it can certainly be done.

Comment: oh that is so nasty, but it might be the only way

Comment: At the time the data in `element` is being hydrated you can do this check in order to remove it from your view code. Do you mind editing the question with that part of your code?

Comment: yeah, I will call String() in the JavaScript instead of the HTML, good idea

Comment: You can also do the check for `null` and `undefined` there as well. Here is a good answer explaining how to check for them as they both resolve to `false`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript