# Send params as reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reference, pass-by-reference

Is there a way in javascript to send a var by reference and initialize it inside a function.

For ex:

```
function init(param){param = function(){}}
var undefinedVar;
init(undefinedVar);
```

undefined var will remain `undefined` after this invocation.

I know that only objects are sent across functions as reference for ex:

```
function init(param){param.attr='';}
var objectVar = {}
init(objectVar);
```

After this the value of objectVar will be `{attr:""}`

Anyone know a way to force this behaviour for non-object variables?

Thanks

Comment: What non-object do you need to pass to function?

Comment: I am wondering why it isn't rather ``getDefault()`` or so

Comment: Nope, primatives are passed by value.

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is passed by value. (Some things happen to be references but they are still passed by value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript) because the OP needs to understand what's the differences between initialized objects and undefined values.

Comment: you can't . every identify in javascript with a non `object` as it's type is passed by value.

Comment: @Alexander what do you mean by rather getDefault()

Comment: @Ele I don't see how this topic is related to the one that you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most "similar" way of simulating the send by reference way that I found is accessing the context of the parent scope sending the reference of the var name as a string:

```
var undefinedVar, undefinedVar2, undefinedVar3;

function init() {
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    this[arguments[i]] = new Function();
  }
}
init('undefinedVar', 'undefinedVar2', 'undefinedVar3');
```

This can be useful for example **initializing or validating arguments** inside a function.

For example instead of having to repeat code like this

```
(function myContext(arg1, arg2, arg3){
  if(!arg1 || (typeof(arg1)!='function')){
    arg1 = new Function();
  }
  if(!arg2 || (typeof(arg1)!='function')){
    arg2 = new Function();
  }
  if(!arg3 || (typeof(arg1)!='function')){
    arg3 = new Function();
  }
  console.log(arguments);  
})()
```

we could do the following

```
function init(context) {
  for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++){
    if(!context[arguments[i]] || (typeof(arg1)!='function'))
      (context[arguments[i]] = new Function());
  }
}

(function myContext(arg1, arg2, arg3){
  init(arguments, 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');
  console.log(arguments);  
})()
```

This prints

> arg1:ƒ anonymous() arg2:ƒ anonymous() arg3:ƒ anonymous()

This helps to avoid duplicity of code in this kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Only primitive types (string, boolean, number, null, undefined) are passed by value in JavaScript.
But array and object are passed by reference.

With an array :

```
function init(param){param.push('hello')}
var undefinedVar =[];
init(undefinedVar);
console.log(undefinedVar); // print ['hello']
```

With an object :

```
function init(param){param['test'] = 'init'}
var undefinedVar = {};
init(undefinedVar);
console.log(undefinedVar); // print {test : 'init'}
```

They are some posts which talk about it :

[Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned in my question "I know that only objects are sent across functions as reference for ex:...", Array or Arguments is just another kind of object in JS