# Why does function(undefined) return string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In console:

```
    >var t = function(undefined){
             return undefined
          }

    >t("ss")
    >"ss"
```

I dont get why it returns a string. Though

```
void(0)
```

always returns undefined

Comment: You've got a function with a parameter called `undefined`, and you pass it a value and return that.  You're returning a variable value as you've overridden `undefined`

Comment: because `undefined` is not a reserved word.

Comment: Because here 'undefined' has been used as a parameter. And in function definition, javascript gave priority to parameter instead of treating as pre-defined keyword.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO:  still,
undefined is a property which you can compare to
like `x === undefined;`

For further information about [undefined](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp) and/or [difference to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting the parameter name to `undefined` in the function expression, you mask the global variable that is also named `undefined`.

When you pass `"ss"` as the first argument, it is assigned to the local variable `undefined`.

When you `return undefined`, you return the value of the local variable `undefined` which is `"ss"` since that is what you assigned to it.

Comment: so my function is similar to this:

Comment: function(x) { return x} right? i just used undefined which happens to be both global var?