# Why is `null + 1 = 1` but `undefined + 1 = NaN`?

Tags: javascript, undefined, nan

`null + 1 = 1`

`undefined + 1 = NaN`

I am not able to understand what is the logic behind this. Shouldn't both have returned same result?

Comment: `Number(null) == 0`, but `Number(undefined) == NaN`.

Comment: Because `Number(null)` is 0 and `Number(undefined)` is NaN

Comment: have a crack with https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs

Comment: Thanks for the link @Edwin (y)

Comment: after jquery upgrade to 3.0, height() method returns undefined instead of null in some cases. somewhere there has appeared a bug because of this so that i have also experienced it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, because that's what the language spec says - looking at [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3):

```
Type        Result
Null        +0
Undefined   NaN
```

And `NaN` + anything is `NaN`

This *might* make some sense from the language perspective: `null` means an explicit empty value whereas undefined implies an unknown value. In some way - zero is the "number empty value" since it is neutral to addition. That said - that's quite a stretch and I think this is generally bad design. In real JavaScript code - you almost never add `null` to things.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin . It makes sense, I was quite confused but now after your explanation it seems quite simple :) . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because `undefined` means its value is not defined yet so it will take `NaN` and when you add 1 to it `NaN + 1` which is resulting that value is still not defined `NaN`

And on the other hand `null + 1` - object have `null` value and your are trying to add 1 so that it will return 1 which assigned to object

You can also refer this for basic difference -
[What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

> undefined means a variable has not been declared, or has been declared
>   but has not yet been assigned a value, null is an assignment value
>   that means “no value”
>   http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/differences-between-undefined-and-null/

The naturality of js of casting variables types is applied in `null + 1` (because null is typeof object), meanwhile it cannot be applied in a "no value" (undefined).

> When JavaScript tries to operate on a "wrong" data type, it will try
>   to convert the value to a "right" type.
>   https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

More details:
https://codeburst.io/javascript-null-vs-undefined-20f955215a2