# Why this javascript code give me Nan in the last line of output? I need the reason please

Tags: javascript

```js
x = 4;
console.log(x);
var x = 10,
  y = 2;

function z(x) {
  while (x > 0) {
    if (x > 0) {
      break;
    } else {
      x = x - y;
      return z(x);
    }
    return x;
  }
}
console.log(x);
console.log(z(x) + z(x + y));
```

I need explain for the output of the last line?, where the output is `NaN`.

Comment: you dont return on all paths.

Comment: When you break out of the loop, you don't `return x;`, since that's inside the loop. Maybe you meant to put that one line down? Or change `break` to `return x`.

Comment: The code doesn't really make sense. You only go into the loop body when `x > 0`, so the `if` condition will always be true.

Comment: @JeremyThille That's wrong, it works in all loops.

Comment: @Barmar I totally mean this code, thank you for the clarity ❤

Comment: z(n) is always undefined. Adding an undefined entity to any other entity gives `NaN`. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550626/why-is-null-1-1-but-undefined-1-nan) for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function z() is always returning `undefined`. So :

```
z(x) & z(x+y) are undefined
```

Javascript **addition on undefined values returns NaN**. So

```
z(x) + z(x+y) is NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Because z(x) and z(x + y) are returning undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning NaN because when you call...

```
console.log(z(x)+z(x+y));
```

not all paths within the function return anything. In fact, in the if block it just breaks and nothing is ever returned.

```
        if(x>0){
           break;
        }
```

If x == 10 then the while loop will just break and nothing is returned. You can fix this by switching out the break; for return x; which is ultimately doing the same thing but not returning NaN.

```
        if(x>0){
           return x;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function z(x) {
  while (x > 0) {
    if (x > 0) {
      break;
    } else {
      x = x - y;
      return z(x);
    }
    return x;
  }
}
```

For this function, think about the case of `x === 10`. The `while` condition is `true`, so we enter that. Next. We get to the `if (x > 0)`, which is true, so the `break;` statement is hit. This breaks out of the while loop, and we exit the function with no return value. Thus, `z(x)` returns `undefined`.

`z(x + y)` similarly returns undefined if you follow the same logic.

`undefined + undefined === NaN`

Comment: The `while` condition is `x > 0`, so that if/else statement is pointless. The while loop already checks the condition on each iteration. Perhaps you should explain what you want the function to do so we can weigh in on what should be modified.

Comment: Modify condition
if(x > 0) to if (x <= 2)

Answer (score 0):

whatever you want to be done, you function does not return anything by itself. Just add return:

```
function z(x) {
  display.log(x, y)
  while (x > 0) {
    if (x > 0) {
      break;
    } else {
      x = x - y;
      return z(x);
    }
    return x;
  }
  return x /// this is what was added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because hits `break` when x > 0:

```
 if (x > 0) {
  break;
```