# How to define empty variable in object literal?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to define an empty variable in an object literal but I'm getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined". Can anyone please help me here? Thanks.

```
var obj = {
   a,
   b: 1
}

console.log(obj.a);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an "empty" variable. Even if you do `var a;`, `a` is implicitly assign the value `undefined`. Is that what you want for this property? Why do you want to declare an "empty" property in the first place? Accessing a non-existing property will already return `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var obj = { a: null, b: 1 }
console.log(obj.a);
```

Later, you can assign a value to a:

```
obj.a = 1;
```

Edit: You can also set the value to undefined, empty string, or any other type:

```
var obj = { 
  a: null, 
  b: undefined,
  c: '',
  d: NaN
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help Damian. Do I need to assign always NULL for an empty var or is there any other way?

Comment: You can have null, undefined, NaN, an empty string, en empty array or a default value of your choice, you just have to put something in there, it can't be `{a:}`

Comment: you can also use `undefined`, I prefer to use `null`, the difference is very subtle. You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, there is no such thing as an "empty" variable. Even if you do `var a;`, `a` is implicitly assigned the value `undefined`.

---

Depending on your use case (you are not providing much information), you may not have to define anything at all.

Accessing a non-existing property already returns `undefined` (which can be considered as "empty"):

```js
var obj = { b: 1 }
console.log(obj.a);
```

Of course if you want `for...in` or `Object.keys` or `.hasOwnProperties` to include/work for `a`, then you have to define it, as shown [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143631/218196);

---

FYI, `{ a, b: 1 }` does not work because it is equivalent to `{a: a, b: 1}` i.e. you are trying to assign the value of *variable* `a` to *property* `a`, but for this to work, *variable* `a` has to exist.