# Returning early from a function: null, explicit undefined, implicit undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

```
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

function sendRequest {
  if (Validate.isNumber(input)) {
    input.focus();
    return;
  }

  // or

  if (Validate.isNumber(input)) {
    input.focus();
    return null;
  }

  // or

  if (Validate.isNumber(input)) {
    return input.focus();
  }

  // start Ajax call
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ...
}
```

Above 3 function have same result (if validation fail ends the function execution)... So what is the difference? Which one is better?

Comment: What happens if `input` is not a number?

Comment: @OriDrori start the Ajax call

Comment: And what does it return?

Comment: @OriDrori No it just send the value to server and save it in the database.

Comment: I would return a promise from the ajax call, and Promise.reject() (with some to show why it was rejected) if the input is a number. In this way you can react to success and failures (server or check).

Comment: `input` appears to be a string in your code (the value of the input element). It does not have a `.focus()` method?

Comment: Why would you want to `return null;`? The usual `return;` results in `undefined`, which should be fine. Also, what does the function usually return if the validation doesn't fail?

Comment: @OriDrori Noo, I am not asking about returning a promise or not, it's just a DOM input field focus(), wondering what is the difference

Comment: I know. If the return value means something - return a promise to cover all cases. If not, just return to terminate the function.

Comment: @Bergi if the input passed the validation, then just a simple ajax call and send it over to server (No response).

Comment: @OriDrori So what is the difference in above 3 ways to terminate a function execution?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of function, so it doesn't matter. Just return.

Comment: @RaxPat If you're not returning anything in the case of doing the ajax call, then you shouldn't return anything in the case of an error either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EsLint have a good rule: [consistent-return](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return)

> Require return statements to either always or never specify values. If
>   any code paths in a function return a value explicitly but some code
>   path do not return a value explicitly, it might be a typing mistake,
>   especially in a large function

[Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](http://airbnb.io/javascript/#functions)

```
// No implicit return with side effects
function foo(callback) {
  const val = callback();
  if (val === true) {
    // Do something if callback returns true
  }
}
```

So what should we return for nothing?

> In JavaScript, `undefined` means a variable has been declared but has
>   not yet been assigned a value.
>
> `null` is an assignment value. It can be assigned to a variable as a
>   representation of no value.

[null vs undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

**TLDR**: `return null`.

**PS** also take a look at [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). If success path return Promise then negative path can `return Promise.resolve(null)` - if consumer of the function already check value inside Promise and doesn't care why it empty.