# Is there any function difference between using != null and != undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, null, operators, undefined, null-check

In javascript, is there any functional difference between using `!= null` and `!= undefined`?

Is there a value you can assign to `myVar` which will cause these two lines of code to evaluate to different results?

```
console.log(myVar != undefined)
console.log(myVar != null)
```

And if you know anything about the performance of these two operations, I'd love to know about that too.

Comment: Performace should be the least of your concerns. What are the possible values of `myVar`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: @r3zaxd1 Useful link, thanks. But my question is different. It's about the inequality operator, not the nature of null and undefined compared.

Comment: @Teemu I mistyped, I'll edit and fix that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no difference** as you can see in below table for JS `==` testing (focus on null/undefined row/column) (src: [here](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/)). So `myVar!=null` is true  only if `myVar` value is not `null` and not `undefined` (same with `myVar != undefined`)

[image]

It looks like both has similar performance (I made test on Mac OS X 10.13.4 HighSierra: Chrome 71.0.3578, Firefox 65.0.0 and Safari 11.1.0 -  you can run test in your browser [here](https://jsperf.com/nullvsundefinedcmp/1))

```
let myVar1=null;
let myVar2=undefined;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no functional difference. `x != undefined` and `x != null` both only evaluate to `false` when `x` is `null` or `undefined`. They both evaluate to true for all other values of `x`.

There is also no performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` and `!=` operators make "type conversion" to compare just the value itself. Then no, there's no difference using "undefinied" or "null" is this case, both represents "empty".

But if you use `===` and `!==` instead, it checks the type and the value, without any type casting. The results for the two lines would be different.

```
myVar = null;
console.log(myVar !== undefined) //true
console.log(myVar !== null) //false
```

Answer (score -3):

Don't confuse [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) and [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) as they are not the same thing.

**null:**

> The value null represents the intentional absence of any object value. It is one of JavaScript's primitive values.

**undefined:**

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined. A method or statement also returns undefined if the variable that is being evaluated does not have an assigned value. A function returns undefined if a value was not returned.

---

If the variable consists of a value that is neither `null` nor `undefined`, then no there is no difference in your condition.

```js
const value = 3;

console.log(value !== undefined) //true
console.log(value !== null) //true
```

However, a better way of testing if the variable is `null` or `undefined` is to use `!` negation as the value `null` or `undefined` will be resolved to true.

```js
const undefinedValue = undefined;
const nullValue = null;

console.log(!undefinedValue);
console.log(!nullValue);
```

Here are some examples of it.

```js
var someVariable = undefined;

console.log(someVariable !== undefined, "; undefined !== undefined");
console.log(someVariable !== null, "; undefined !== null");

var someVariable = null;

console.log(someVariable !== undefined, "; null !== undefined");
console.log(someVariable !== null, "; null !== null");


var someVariable = undefined;
console.log(!someVariable);

var someVariable = null;
console.log(!someVariable);
```