# TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, data-structures, queue

- I am trying to solve the graph datastructure problem of hacker rank.
- My method should return the minimal cost of providing libraries to all.
- Providing my hacker rank question here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/torque-and-development/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=graphs&isFullScreen=true
- I am planning to use BFS and solve the problem.
- so I read some articles and found this link  https://medium.com/basecs/breaking-down-breadth-first-search-cebe696709d9
- but the problem is I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
- I used the medium code.
- providing my code snippet below.
- can you tell me how to fix it.

```or-tag-here
    'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/\s*$/, '')
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.replace(/\s*$/, ''));

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

// Complete the roadsAndLibraries function below.
function roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities) {
    console.log("roadsAndLibraries n--->", n);
    console.log("roadsAndLibraries c_lib--->", c_lib);
    console.log("roadsAndLibraries c_road--->", c_road);
    console.log("roadsAndLibraries cities--->", cities);
    var m = new Map();
    m.set('a', 2);
    m.set('b', 3);
    m.set('b', 3);
    m.set('b', 2);
    m.set('b', 1);

    console.log("map value--->", m);
        // Check that a root node exists.

    // if (rootNode === null) {
    //     return;
    // }

    // Check that a root node exists.
    if (n === null) {
        console.log("n root node--->", n);
        return;
    }

    // Create our queue and push our root node into it.
    // var queue = [];
    // queue.push(rootNode);

    // Create our queue and push our root node into it.
    var queue = [];
    queue.push(n);

    console.log(" queue.push--->", queue);


    while (queue.length > 0) {
        // Create a reference to currentNode, at the top of the queue.
        var currentNode = queue[0];

        // If currentNode has a left child node, add it to the queue.
        if (currentNode.left !== null) {
            queue.push(currentNode.left)
        }
        // If currentNode has a right child node, add it to the queue.
        if (currentNode.right !== null) {
            queue.push(currentNode.right)
        }
        // Remove the currentNode from the queue.
        queue.shift()
    }




}

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);
    console.log("ws--->", ws);


    const q = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    console.log("q--->", q);

    for (let qItr = 0; qItr < q; qItr++) {
        const nmC_libC_road = readLine().split(' ');
        console.log("nmC_libC_road--->", nmC_libC_road);

        const n = parseInt(nmC_libC_road[0], 10);
        console.log("n--->", n);


        const m = parseInt(nmC_libC_road[1], 10);
        console.log("m--->", m);

        const c_lib = parseInt(nmC_libC_road[2], 10);
        console.log("c_lib--->", c_lib);

        const c_road = parseInt(nmC_libC_road[3], 10);
        console.log("c_road--->", c_road);

        let cities = Array(m);
        console.log("cities--->", cities);

        for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            cities[i] = readLine().split(' ').map(citiesTemp => parseInt(citiesTemp, 10));
        }

        const result = roadsAndLibraries(n, c_lib, c_road, cities);
        console.log("result--->", result);

        ws.write(result + '\n');
    }

    ws.end();
}
```

**after compilation**

```or-tag-here
Input (stdin)Download
2
3 3 2 1
1 2
3 1
2 3
6 6 2 5
1 3
3 4
2 4
1 2
2 3
5 6
Your Output (stdout)
~ no response on stdout ~
Expected OutputDownload
4
12
Debug output
ws---> WriteStream {
  _writableState:
   WritableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     finalCalled: false,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     destroyed: false,
     decodeStrings: true,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     corked: 0,
     sync: true,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     bufferedRequest: null,
     lastBufferedRequest: null,
     pendingcb: 0,
     prefinished: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     emitClose: false,
     bufferedRequestCount: 0,
     corkedRequestsFree:
      { next: null,
        entry: null,
        finish: [Function: bound onCorkedFinish] } },
  writable: true,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  path:
   '/tmp/submission/20190702/20/31/hackerrank-d27db21d31abaff7353d49d7e433da3a/0.userout',
  fd: null,
  flags: 'w',
  mode: 438,
  start: undefined,
  autoClose: true,
  pos: undefined,
  bytesWritten: 0,
  closed: false }
q---> 2
nmC_libC_road---> [ '3', '3', '2', '1' ]
n---> 3
m---> 3
c_lib---> 2
c_road---> 1
cities---> [ <3 empty items> ]
roadsAndLibraries n---> 3
roadsAndLibraries c_lib---> 2
roadsAndLibraries c_road---> 1
roadsAndLibraries cities---> [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]
map value---> Map { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1 }
 queue.push---> [ 3 ]
```

Comment: What's the input coming from `stdin`? Can you include it as well?

Comment: @FZs updated output too...can you let me know if I gave you correct info

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that `queue.push(currentNode.left)` (and `queue.push(currentNode.right)`) is being executed as `null` and `undefined` [are different in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript).  On the second time through the loop there will be two undefined elements in the queue, `currentNode` will now be undefined, and so of course you cannot access undefined's `left` or `right` property.

Why is this happening?  Basically you haven't finished translating the Medium code's BFS implementation into what's needed for HackerRank.  The BFS code is expecting the queue to contain node objects, and HackerRank's input is definitely not anything resembling a node.  As it currently stands, the only item in your queue is a single number, which contains no `left` or `right` attributes.  The exercise will involve, at the minimum, translating their input into a node structure suitable for BFS (if BFS is even an appropriate solution).

One possible solution might be to expand the `null` checks to also include `undefined`.  Another might be to make sure everything that enters your queue is a proper node, with an initialized `left` and `right` value, even if that value is `null`.  For intermediate testing, I'd expect replacing `queue.push(n);` with `let aBoringNode = {left: null, right: null}; queue.push(aBoringNode);` to at least get you past the current error and perform a valid (if exceedingly boring) BFS execution.

Comment: hey updated the whole code in the question, can you guys update the code...so confusing :(

Answer (score 2):

```
const n = parseInt(nmC_libC_road[0], 10);
console.log("n--->", n);
```

`queue` is a array contains `n`, `n` is a number, it cannot be used as an object. I think it's the problem.

So, I think you need to change `n` to `m` instead.

Comment: Others have pointed out that `n` is not a node, and how that leads to the error being thrown. `m` is also not a node with `left` and `right` attributes, so changing `n` to `m` isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but remember in JavaScript undefined and null are not the same thing. So undefined !== null is truthy.  In your loop you should add checks that currentNode.right and currentNode.left are not undefined

Comment: hey updated the whole code in the question, can you guys update the code...so confusing :(

Answer (score 0):

Just scanned the problem description, it says:

> roadsAndLibraries has the following parameters:
>
> n: **integer, the number of cities**

But obviously in your code, you are treating n as 'node'...
It's truely a 'TypeError' as javascript indicates.

Comment: hey updated the whole code in the question, can you guys update the code...so confusing :(