# What actually is an undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am asking this question after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript) question.

**NOTE** I know the difference between `null` and `undefined`.

Let me show you an example,

```js
let a = {};

console.log(a.test); // undefined
```

Now what if I add a property with `test1: undefined`

```
a.test1 = undefined;

console.log(test1); // undefined
console.log(a); // { test1: undefined }
```

Now tell me what is `undefined`. Is it a value or something

Comment: *"`undefined` is a property of the global object. That is, it is a variable in global scope. The initial value of `undefined` is the primitive value `undefined`."* - From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a one of the javascript primitive types.

Javascript will assign `undefined` to any variable or object's property which is not declared.

`undefined` is one of the falsy values in javascript like `null`.

```
let a = {};

console.log(a.test); //  undefined
```

In the above snippet `test` property is undefined cause javascript assigns undefined to variables or object's properties which declared but not assigned any value.

```
a.test1 = undefined;

console.log(test1); // undefined
console.log(a); // { test1: undefined }
```

In the above snippet, you are specifically assigning undefined to `test1` property of `a`. If you don't assign any value then it will contain undefined by default JS behavior as shown below

```
a.test1; 
console.log(a); // { test1: undefined }
```

**One more interesting feature of undefined is with JSON. JSON.stringify will ignore all properties of object which are undefined.**

```
let obj = {a:1, b:undefined};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // {a:1}
```

[For more about primitive types undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: first Thing `console.log(test1)` throw an error while you run this statement second `a.test1;`  is in invalid statement and third thing is `undefined` and `null`  treated different  check this `let obj = {a:1, b:undefined, c: null}; console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`

Comment: @ManjeetThakur Yes, you are right. But anyhow, you both solved my problem.. Thanks

Comment: @GurkiratSingh my answer assumed that you have already declared `a` object.

Answer (score 0):

**undefined** is a falsy value in Javascript.
If a variable is not assigned with some value, then JS automatically assigne a value of undefined.

```
let a = {};
```

In this case, the object is blank. And accessing any value of `a` would give undefined.
However, if some values are assigned to `a`, in your case

```
a.test1 = undefined;
```

In this, a has some values, so a.test1 will not give you undefined that was assigned by default to the variable as you have already assigned some values to it. And on accessing it, you will get the value assigned i.e `undefined`