# why does javascript have both null and undefined?

Tags: javascript

why does javascript have `null` and `undefined`? they both seem to mean the same thing, `there's nothing here` and they are both falsey, as they should be. But it means, for example if I want to check if something exists but it could be `{}`, `[]`, `0` or some other falsey thing i have to check

```js
if(thing !== undefined && thing !== null)
```

also, I know that `typeof null` is `Object` but `typeof {}` is also `Object` while `typeof undefined` is `"undefined"` but

```js
const nullVariable = null;
console.log(nullVariable.x) // => error
const emptyVariable = {};
console.log(emptyVariable.x) // => undefined
const undefinedVariable;
console.log(undefinedVariable.x) // => error
```

also, `undefined` is supposed to mean that the variable hasn't been declared yet, but you can declare a variable like

```
const undefinedVariable = undefined;
```

so it has been defined but it has not yet been defined?

so what I am saying is while they have different semantic meanings, one means a variable that hasn't been declared and on means a variable with no value, they seem to have the functionality and they are both false, trying to get a property form them will return an error.

basically what I am asking is why do we need both, why not just use one like python with `None` or lower level languages like java and c++ with `Null`?

Comment: Not Really, they are two completely different things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: @MosiaThabo, no I read that post before I made this one, and that states the difference between but not the point of having both of them

Comment: @ggorlen that was meant to display how it is unintuitive that `typeof null` is `Object` but you can't access properties from it, just like you can't access properties from undefined, I can see how you are confused so I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Apparently the explanation for that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript#comment9782995_5076962).

Comment: That point is also addressed in the duplicate ...

Comment: Related: https://2ality.com/2013/05/history-undefined.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you think about their pusposes to better understand the difference.

The value `null` represents the **intentional absence** of any **object value**.  It's never assigned by the runtime.

Meanwhile any variable that has not been assigned a value is of type `undefined`. Methods, statements and functions can also return `undefined`. You also get `undefined` when you call **a non-existent property or method of an object**.

`undefined` has nothing to do with an empty value. For example:

```
console.log(5 + undefined);
// expected output: NaN
console.log(5 + null);
// expected output: 5
```

The distinction between both is useful given that JavaScript is dynamically typed and objects are dynamic "bags" of properties that can be changed at runtime.

```
let car = {type: "Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
console.log(car.type);
// expected output: "Fiat"
console.log(car.price);
// expected output: undefined
car.price = null;
console.log(car.price);
// expected output: null
car.price = 2000;
console.log(car.price);
// expected output:2000
```

Comment: Yes. there is a semantical difference between undefined and null. But is it having both really worth of all complications?

Answer (score 2):

imagine a glass of water;

if it exists, but doesn't have any water inside; it is `null`.

if there is no glass at all; it is `undefined`.

Comment: yes but in python, if you have a glass of water, it exists and there is no water in it then it is `None` and if there is no glass it is also `None` and there are no errors that come up due to that fact, also you would think, if the glass exists but has no water then `glass.water` would return undefined but it returns an error, `can not get property "water" of null`

Comment: @davidsnyder two different errors, thrown when you call `glass.water` on `null` glass  or `undefined` glass. one is `typeError`, the other is `referenceError`.

Comment: that's not the point, the point is they both throw errors.

Comment: @davidsnyder dark-green and light-green both are `green`; but they are different. thats an old argument bro.. I suggest you read [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) book by getify

Comment: you have a point there, but I just tested it again and they both return `TypeError` as seen [Here](https://i.imgur.com/f5rRG33.png) but even if they didn't thrown the same type of error that still doesn't explain the **need** for both of them

Comment: @davidsnyder `let dd = null; dd.j` run this; and this `jj.d` nothing else; btw javascript is written in 10 days in the early days not event meant to go this far; but its architecture was brilliant.. reading a little about it's history may resolve some of this concerns :)