# Typescript type declaration difference

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and trying to figure out what the difference between the following 3 types is:

```
field1?: string | null;
field2?: string;
field3:  string;
```

Any reference to Typescript docs to help me understand would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface A { field1?: string | null; }
```

Here you have a field that can be omitted (or `undefined`). That is denoted with the `?:` notation. And if the field is defined, it must be either, `string` or `null`.

```
// The following are all allowed
const a1: A = { field1: 'abc' } // string
const a2: A = { field1: null } // null
const a3: A = {} // omitted
const a4: A = { field1: undefined } // explicit undefined
```

---

```
interface B { field2?: string; }
```

This means the field may be omitted or `undefined`. But if it is defined it must be a string. This means `null` is not allowed.

```
const b1: B = { field2: 'abc' } // string
const b2: B = { field2: null } // ERROR: field2 cannot be null
const b3: B = {} // omitted
const b4: B = { field2: undefined } // explicit undefined
```

---

```
interface C { field3: string; }
```

This means the field must be a string. It may never be omitted.

```
const c1: C = { field3: 'abc' } // string
const c2: C = { field3: null } // ERROR: field3 cannot be null
const c3: C = {} // ERROR: field3 cannot be omitted
const c4: C = { field3: undefined } // ERROR: field3 cannot be undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=73&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7JsCAbAEwEYB+ALmQGcwpQBzZAH2RAFc88BuZAXwCg+AekHIAKgAsUMAPYdpAd3rI4UFHA7K58iAT4JpIasqIV0AXkzZchE8gDkcAEYI7vZMKo16eg0bgAmU2QLLBx8Ygo2DR53ESi8H0MwZQBmIJCYj2kAW2AwSF19JOUAFnTLMJsKVhACCBwQHTcPCAAPAAc8YAQ85Bq6hp0BPlBIWEQUACEK6wJ-ck9aEDpufkSjR1tpkKtwwPsnF2aRaiW6deTHfe2Zvcj2PGPkAFEAJVeAeVeKSrnkBDgIBA0kuKHiF2QjjSyBuGEyIhyeQKEMcZRhwVuhH2-XqoCa8OQbU63V6OMGugEo2g8CQyAAwpiCNDTvRVgIikYELYGTtftCHM5XASWcsIQh9jzGdD4k83p9vrssf9AcDQSwHmLoZK4bEXu8vj9ZillUCQZCUIj8kMOckEGjtYqmdVarjGgRZfqFb9-CbVea+i7yUA)

---

Also relevant, a question about the different between `null` and `undefined`: [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can google it by youself. Optional property/parameter.
In your example:

```
field1?: string | null;
```

optional property field1 of type string or null. Optional means not required and currently undefined. That's no error.

```
field2?: string;
```

optional property field2 of type only string

```
field3:  string;
```

declared property of type string, but actually now it has undefined, that's error, and field3 has to be implemented in class constructor.