# Null or undefined for data?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using `vuex-module-decorators` and I would like to know if I should set the default value of a data property to `null` or `undefined`. Example:

```
export default class ComponentName extends Vue {
 post: BlogPost | null = null
}
```

or

```
export default class ComponentName extends Vue {
 post: BlogPost | undefined = undefined
}
```

Is there a right answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: nop, that's a vue question, not a javascript question.

Comment: Data types are inherited from javascript, so that answer applies to your question.

Comment: It doesn't :). Check the answer, there is context in `null` and `undefined` for state in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If state value cannot be determined, it MUST be initialized with null.
> Just like wheels: number | null = null.

From the [docs](https://championswimmer.in/vuex-module-decorators/pages/core/state.html).