# Why do I get Type error: Object is possibly 'null'?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular project I want to implement deleting items but when I use `this.currentClient.id` or `.this.currentClient.name` i get this error:

> Type error: Object is possibly 'null'

This is a fragment with updating currentClient data and deleting function:

```
export class ClientDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  currentClient = null;
  message = '';

getClient(id: string | null): void {
    this.clientService.get(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.currentClient = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

  deleteClient(): void {
    this.clientService.delete(this.currentClient.id)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.router.navigate(['/clients']);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
```

I can't find out why it can be null :(

Comment: Because you’re initializing it with a null value? `currentClient = null`. Perform a null value check before accessing the sub properties, or use optional chaining, ie `this.currentClient?.id`

Answer (score 0):

Your editor is right, and I also believe that this object can be null. Why? Because of this line:

```js
currentClient = null;
```

From an outside point of view, I can call the delete function at any time, meaning that your `currentClient` variable can actuaby null because you initialize it as such!

There are two main options for you to solve this:

- Check the value of `this.currentClient` ->  `if(this.currentClient){......}`
- Use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).

The second solution should be used ONLY IF you know that your variable will never be  [null or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript) once you exit the constructor of your class.

You might also want to have a look at the nullable operator. `private currentClient?: Client;`

Comment: Thank you, I tried checking the value but it didn't work and I get the same error