# Undefined vs Reference Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the reasons for the difference in the response to the following:

#### case a

`var x` is not declared. So, when I run:

```js
console.log(x)
```

I get the expected response: `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`

#### case b

```
let obj = { }
console.log(obj.x)
```

In this case, `undefined` gets printed.

#### Question

In both cases, the binding `x` is not defined. What explains the difference in the responses ?

Comment: You need to format your question so we can better understand. If you `console.log(x)`, for example, why would _`a`_ be undefined?

Comment: Its saying case a) and case b) @Andy. Both using x as variable/property name.

Comment: Variables and properties are different things. Different rules.

Comment: I'm aware of that @TheFool which is why _`a` being undefined is the expected response_ is weird because `a` isn't declared anywhere, and why I wanted the OP to edit the question.

Comment: Apologies. The response was  'Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

**Case A: Undefined variables**

JavaScript exception "variable is not defined" occurs when there is a non-existent variable referenced somewhere. Forgetting to define a variable before referencing it may be the most common reference error trigger for developers.

```js
let firstName = "xyz"
console.log(lastName); // Uncaught ReferenceError: lastName is not defined
```

[Documentation for ReferenceError: "x" is not defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined)

**Case B: Undefined**

JavaScript warning "reference to undefined property" occurs when a script attempted to access an object property that doesn't exist.

```js
let obj = { }
console.log(obj.x)
```

[Undefined Error Documentation - Reference Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Undefined_prop)

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question we first need to understand undefined and and console.log method and it's return  value.

**undefined**:

1. A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined.
2. A method or statement also returns undefined if the variable that is being evaluated does not have an assigned value.
3. A function returns undefined if a value was not returned.

**console.log** : It returns the value of the parameter given.

Your scenario falls under 3rd point, because console.log could not return any value for passed parameter.It returned undefined.

References:[Undefined:Developer.Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

[console.log:GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-console-log-with-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

in the first case, you did not declare a variable called `x` so it will be not declared but if you did it like this:

```
console.log(x); // undefined
var x;
```

it will not throw any errors. in the second case, there is an existing variable called obj but there is no property called x so it will be undefined and it will not throw any errors except if something depends on it so that is it. I hope my answer helps you.