# Filter objects with a specific property from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have inserted objects with a new property(property name - "Type") to a JS array. After that, I need to filter objects with that property(which is "Type") to a new array.

```
var arr = [
{ID: 1, Name: "Name1"},
{ID: 2, Name: "Name2"}]

var newObject = {
ID: 3,
Name: 'Test',
Type: 'New'
};

arr.push(newObject);
```

I tried

```
var newVal = arr.filter(x => x.Type !== null);
```

it returns all the object from array

result should be

```
[{ ID: 3, Name: "Test", Type: "New" }]
```

Comment: there is no object with `Type === null` in your array. But `Type === undefined` for both objects, ie `null !== undefined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check for `null`. Use `undefined` instead:

```
var newVal = arr.filter(x => x.Type !== undefined);
```

Check [this definition of `null` and `undefined`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/undefined-vs-null-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Null%3A%20It%20is%20the%20intentional,It%20is%20the%20global%20object.):

> Null: It is the intentional absence of the value. It is one of the primitive values of JavaScript.
> Undefined: It means the value does not exist in the compiler. It is the global object.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is undefined instead of null

The code below will get any type EXCEPT falsy types like `"Type" : 0` and `"Type": ""`

```js
let arr = [
{ID: 1, Name: "Name1"},
{ID: 2, Name: "Name2"}]

var newObject = {
ID: 3,
Name: 'Test',
Type: 'New'
};

arr.push(newObject);

const newVal = arr.filter(x => { 
  console.log(x.Type) 
  return x.Type; // not undefined, not null, not empty string.
  });
  
console.log(newVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Javascript (ES 2021 I think), you can use nullish coalescing:

```js
var arr = [
{ID: 1, Name: "Name1"},
{ID: 2, Name: "Name2"}]

var newObject = {
ID: 3,
Name: 'Test',
Type: 'New'
};

arr.push(newObject);

var newVal = arr.filter(x => x.Type ?? false);
console.log(newVal)
```

Nullish coalescing is good for when a variable is defined, but it is technically false. With `a ?? b`, either `a` or `b` will be returned. If `a` is `undefined`, `null`, then `b` will be returned. Otherwise, `a` will be returned. You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

Comment: *"" and 0 will return true with nullish coalescing.* That's wrong. The null coalescing operator `??` won't return `true` or `false`, it will return whatever the first or second operand in `aa ?? bb`  is. If `aa` is `null` or `undefined` it will return `bb` else it will return `aa`. In this particular case, the `??` is probably not needed at all (depending on the semantics OP wants), because the result will be exactly the same as with `arr.filter(x => x.Type)`

Comment: @derpirscher right, I forgot that `||` and `??` return either a or b. I wish `??` returned true though; I feel like that would make things easier. I'll edit my question, thanks!