# Why do I have to explicitly set a default value of null to an optional parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm a Kotlin developer and touched some typescript lately. I ran into a type issue that originated in

```
site_url?: string
site_domain?: string
```

and was solved with these changes:

```
site_url: string | null
site_domain: string | null
```

I read into it and ? means that the field is optional. If it is optional, it can be null. Is the issue that I did not set a default value `null` and wanted to do it implicitly? Why do we need to specify a 'default value' of null if the parameter is marked as optional?

I also had to change the method from

```
export const doSomething = async (domain: string): Promise<Something> => {
```

to

```
export const doSomething = async (domain: string | null): Promise<Something> => {
```

The error that was, for me, really hard to debug was:

```
Type error: Argument of type '(domain: string) => Promise<Something>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string | undefined, index: number, array: (string | undefined)[]) => Promise<Something>'.
```

Comment: `site_url?: string` is perfectly normal code and can work in many situations. How did it fail for you?

Comment: I updated the question with error message and calling details

Comment: "*If it is optional, it can be null.*" no, optional means it can be missing (or `undefined`) but not `null`. Assuming you have `strictNullChecks` enabled. With the strict rule enabled, you cannot assign `null` to something marked optional but not marked that it can receive a `null`.

Comment: Just for clarity: https://i.redd.it/vy1n3ionqgg51.png :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional parameters in TS/JS give a value of `undefined` rather than `null` when accessed. You can also explicitly pass `undefined` as a value.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript) goes into detail on the differences.

If you need to use `null` specifically for an external typed library, you would need to catch `undefined` and set it to `null`.

Comment: mh yes, true. so an object definition without content or no object definition at all.