# Difference between !a and a=== null

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between `!a` and `a===null` in JavaScript?
I am working on a project where it is behaving differently.

I am not talking in terms of Boolean values though as `!true` will not me same as `true===null`

`if (!this.props.user)` is resulting to true,

where as if `(this.props.user === null)` is resulting to false

Comment: One possibility: `undefined === null` is false

Comment: All falsy values except `null`?

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript

Comment: `!a` would catch `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`.

Comment: When everything else fails, try to [read the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!a` will return `true` if `a` is any [Falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (e.g, `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `0`...)

`a === null` will only return true if `a` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

like **@Spectric** answer.
`a === null` need to have same type to return true. 
even the value has falsy value (e.g, `false`, `undefined`, `0`).
 it will return false because the value is not same with `null`